# Princípio aberto/fechado - como entender isso?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, solid

Em orientação a objetos existe o SOLID sendo que um dos princípios é o aberto/fechado que eu aprendi da seguinte forma: "os componentes de software devem estar abertos para extensão e fechados para modificação" sendo que componentes inclui classes, métodos, etc. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, eu não consigo entender como isso realmente funciona na prática.

O que acontece é que eu consigo imaginar várias razões que podem requerer modificação de uma classe, entre elas mudança nos requisitos do sistema sendo desenvolvido. Apesar de eu estar a par dessa ideia, meu cliente não está e ele pode muito facilmente mudar de ideia em alguns pontos que exijam revisão na lógica em si dentro das classes.

Nesses casos não consigo ver uma forma de resolver isso somente com herança. Se o que está mudando é realmente como o método deve funcionar, eu vou precisar modificar ele.

Dessa forma, o que realmente o principio aberto/fechado quer dizer e como se usa ele na prática?

Comment: Relevante: http://qualityisspeed.blogspot.com.br/2014/08/why-i-dont-teach-solid.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, exemplos didáticos não são aplicáveis a todas as situações reais. Cabe a você entender o princípio e aplicar onde quer que ele traga benefícios reais ao seu projeto.

Sobre o princípio Aberto/Fechado, vou exemplificar.

Suponha que você tem um sistema que processa pagamentos. Você pode implementar um método da seguinte forma:

```java
class Pagamento {
    void efetuarPagamento(String tipo, Integer codigo, Double valor) {
        if ("BOLETO".equals(tipo)) {
            new IntegracaoBoletoBanco().pagarBoleto(codigo, valor);
        } else if ("CARTAO".equals(tipo)) {
            new IntegracaoCartaoBanco().pagarCartao(codigo, valor);
        } else if ("DINHEIRO".equals(tipo)) {
            new IntegracaoContaBanco().pagarDinheiro(valor);
        }
    }
}
```

O código acima é fictício, mas acho que dá para entender a proposta dele.

Note que o código é altamente acoplado e deverá ser modificado sempre que um tipo de pagamento for acrescentado, retirado ou modificado. Ou seja, ele é aberto para modificação.

Podemos refatorar esse código de forma que o algoritmo fique mais genérico. Vejamos:

```java
class Pagamento {
    void efetuarPagamento(IntegracaoBanco integracaoBanco, DadosPagamento dadosPagamento) {
        integracaoBanco.pagar(dadosPagamento);
    }
}
```

Considere que `IntegracaoBanco` e `DadosPagamento` são interfaces e podem ter várias implementações.

Dessa vez nosso código ficou muito mais simples e permite você criar novas implementações de pagamento através das interfaces ou estendendo as classes que já fazem parte do sistema **sem mexer no código existente**.

No meu entendimento esse é o conceito mais importante, pois quando não mexemos no que já existe, a chance de você "quebrar" o que já existe é "infinitamente" menor.

No exemplo acima, o parâmetro `IntegracaoBanco` é um tipo de Inversão de Controle (IoC), que é outro princípio do SOLID. Geralmente eles acabam se relacionando uns com os outros. O outro parâmetro encapsula os dados utilizados.

Resumindo, o princípio Aberto/Fechado poderia ser entendido como uma implementação que permite adicionar novas funcionalidades sem mexer no código existente. Em outras palavras:

> Não precisamos alterar o conteúdo das classes, basta criar novas implementações de interfaces ou sobrescrever os métodos de classes existentes.

### Para um exemplo muito mais completo [veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281385/227).

Comment: Pesquisando um pouco sobre o assunto cheguei a conclusão que por pouco não dei uma resposta errada, entretanto acho que posso tecnicamente baseá-la no `Meyer's OCP`. Sua resposta é mt boa, e é baseada no `Polymorphic OCP` que é mais moderno. Ainda preciso estudar para ter ctz que não falei nenhuma besteira pois ainda não pude confirmar por princípios tudo que eu disse. Sobre `exemplos didáticos não são aplicáveis a todas as situações reais`, vale muito ser citado, eu mesmo fiquei bem preocupado na hora de criar um exemplo, enquanto apenas adicionar esse texto poderia ter me deixado mais livre.

Comment: @Math Pra falar a verdade eu não sabia sobre essa distinção, mas acabei de ler um pouco e vi que na verdade eu fiz um mix das duas. Obrigado.

Comment: Só pra constar, eu postei meu comentário antes de sua pergunta ter sido aceita, rs.. Sobre os termos, eu também não conhecia, entretanto eu comecei a pesquisar pois após ler sua resposta desconfiei que eu tinha falado abobrinha, mas agora cheguei a conclusão de que a parte que eu falo de novas LPs se baseia mais no polymorphic, já o resto se baseia apenas no Meyer. Ou seja, apesar da minha confusão minha resposta é válida =). Entretanto os conceitos não eram claros para mim na hora que eu escrevia, provavelmente editarei minha resposta expondo isso. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @Math Assim que se aprende!

Comment: @utluiz sua resposta levantou a questão se é possível adicionar novas classes à arquitetura sem editar código já existente para poder instanciar/acessar essas novas classes, e sem utilizar reflexão para encontrar-se essas novas classes automaticamente. Tenho conversado com o Piovezan sobre isso nos comentários [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/279079/68989), você poderia, por favor, esclarecer esse assunto na sua resposta para sanar essa dúvida à quem ler sua resposta e porventura tiver essa mesma dúvida? Agradeço desde já. :)

Comment: @Douglas Adicionei uma resposta com muitos detalhes lá na outra pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281385/227

Answer (score 9):

O principio aberto/fechado preza basicamente por não estragar o que já está pronto. Ou seja, pense na sua linguagem de programação preferida, agora suponha que você tem inúmeros aplicativos desenvolvidos nessa linguagem, entretanto um belo dia sai uma versão mais nova dessa linguagem e você é obrigado a voltar consertando todos seus aplicativos desenvolvidos até o presente momento pois a linguagem simplesmente mudou a maneira de fazer algo e não deu continuidade ao jeito antigo de se fazer. Agora multiplique isso por todos os desenvolvedores dessa linguagem em torno do globo terrestre. Já pensou no caos que isso geraria?

Em proporções menores nós também desenvolvemos códigos que podem ser usados por outras classes nossas em outros aplicativos ou até mesmo usado por outras pessoas.

Um excelente exemplo (simplificado) de evitar ferir esse princípio são os getters e os setters.

Exemplo: Você fez um código sem os getters e setters, entretanto você percebeu que alguns dos atributos da sua classe precisam de uma validação, digamos uma data qualquer que não pode ser definida como antes da data atual, pois na verdade ela deve se referir a algo no futuro. Ou seja, não deveria permitir algo assim:

```
material.dataPrevistaDeChegada = new DateTime("01/01/2014");
```

Para consertar isso você resolve por o get e o set para o campo da data e mudar o acesso de publico para privado. Fazendo isso todos os códigos que faziam o acesso ao atributo diretamente estarão quebrados, pois não é mais possível acessar o atributo do jeito que era feito antes.

Entretanto, se o atributo sempre foi privado e sempre teve o get e o set nada impede você de implementar a verificação do valor antes de alterar a sua data, para isso basta você melhorar o seu código sem quebrar o código das outras classes.

Exemplo de código usando o set sem pensar na validação:

```
public void setDataPrevistaDeChegada(DateTime dataPrevistaDeChegada) {
    this.dataPrevistaDeChegada = dataPrevistaDeChegada;
}
```

Código quando você percebeu que a validação era importante:

```
public void setDataPrevistaDeChegada(DateTime dataPrevistaDeChegada) {
    if(dataPrevistaDeChegada.isBefore(new DateTime(DateTime.now()))) {
        return;
    }
    this.dataPrevistaDeChegada = dataPrevistaDeChegada;
}
```

O `return` é apenas um exemplo, se quiser você pode atribuir um valor padrão desde que isso seja aceitável para sua aplicação.

No exemplo acima você estendeu seu código, entretanto você não mudou ele. Ok, na prática você *fez uma modificação*, mas essa modificação é transparente para quem depende da sua classe, logo, você pode mudar detalhes internos desde que isso não afete quem dependa da sua classe, isso seria chamado de extensão ao invés de mudança.

Modificando o set, você garantiu que o atributo da data não vai mudar caso a condição colocada dentro do set não for atendida, esse exemplo é apenas uma boa simplificação de como não ferir o princípio, vale a pena ser citada por ser amplamente conhecida entre os desenvolvedores.

Soluções mais avançadas para garantir o princípio do aberto/fechado seriam basicamente uma modelagem mais elaborada de suas classes, como por exemplo o padrão de projeto Fábrica (Factory Design Pattern, em inglês) , que é um intermédio entre a classe que deseja uma nova instância de classe e a classe que fornecerá esse novo objeto. Dentro da Fábrica você põe as regras de criação do objeto, caso um dia você precise mudar essas regras você poderá fazer sem obrigar a modificar as classes que dependem dela.

Answer (score 3):

O principio **aberto/fechado** deve ser aplicado quando o cenário exige que haja garantia de que os métodos de uma classe filha não sofreram alterações e funcionam exatamente como implementados originalmente.

Nesses casos quando algo novo precisa ser introduzido isso é feito por meio de um **novo método (extensão)** e não por meio de um **override (modificação)**.

Ele faz mais sentido quando analisado e aplicado no contexto dos demais princípios SOLID e não  necessáriamente é algo a ser seguido. O **Override** de métodos é em muitos casos algo útil, e nestes cenários deve sim, ser utilizados.