# O que é injeção de dependência?

Tags: c#, design-pattern, injeção-de-dependência

Tenho ouvido falar bastante sobre injeção de dependência. A pergunta é: Como, quando e para que usar?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101

Comment: Também conhecido como [*Dependency Injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) ou *DI*.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Ótimo assunto, porém isso dá um livro de resposta.

Recomendo o estudo sobre *Design Patterns*.

## Injeção de dependência

É um *Design Pattern* que prega um tipo de controle externo, um *container*, uma classe, configurações via arquivo, etc., inserir uma dependência em uma outra classe.

Tentando melhorar: "O padrão de injeção de dependências visa remover dependências desnecessárias entre as classes".

## Exemplo

```
public class PedidosController : Controller
{
    private IPedidoRepository _pedidoRepositorio;
    public PedidosController(IPedidoRepository pedidoRepositorio)
    {
       _pedidoRepositorio = pedidoRepositorio;
    }
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var pedidos = _pedidoRepositorio.ObterTodos();
        return View(pedidos);
    }
}
```

Para entender o conceito é também necessário aprofundar o conhecimento em **Inversão de Controle** e um pouco do principio SOLID, afinal ele é a Letra D (Dependa de uma abstração e não de uma implementação).

**Exemplo de algo incorreto, algo muito acoplado.**

```
public class PedidosController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var pedidoRepositorio = new PedidoRepository();
        var pedidos = pedidoRepositorio.ObterTodos();
        return View(pedidos);
    }
}
```

## Recomendo as seguintes leituras

- [Injeção depedencia - Microsoft ASP.Net Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [.NET - Inversão de Controle (IoC) e Injeção de Dependência (DI)](http://www.macoratti.net/11/07/ioc_di1.htm)
- [Design Patterns - Injeção de Dependência com C#](http://www.devmedia.com.br/design-patterns-injecao-de-dependencia-com-c/23671)

E o grande Martin Fowler:

- [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

**Resumindo:**
Você coloca a responsabilidade das classes externas na classe que está chamando e não na classe chamada.

Comment: Tem um livro ótimo e barato e em português:
Refatoração - Aperfeiçoando o Projeto de Código Existente
Na Saraiva estava 80 reais e valia muito a pena

Comment: Legal pela dica. Vou trocar de emprego e lá vou precisar bastante dos conceitos. Esse é um pattern não previsto pelo GoF, certo? Preciso sim estudar padrões de projetos e não somente a entender, mas principalmente implementá-los. Valeu pela dica.

Comment: Design Pattern seria Padrões de projetos. e ai existem varios GoF, GRASP,etc, apesar de cada um ter seus padrões creio que todos caminham para uma mesma finalidade, Eu acho que o conceito SOLID entendido na integra ajuda em todos os principios.

Comment: O link passado acima, do Macoratti, o qual estou lendo nesse momento, está me dando uma noção legal sobre o assunto. É claro que é necessário muito mais, mas já é um começo, uma bússola que aponta o norte neste assunto.

Comment: Pessoal, vocês têm noção do foi construído aqui? Tenho certeza que esse post, não porque foi meu, mas é uma verdadeira enciclopédia no assunto. Muito rico em informações sobre o assunto e detalhes.

Comment: Aproveitando utLuiz, vejo que sua resposta é mais formal, sem uma opinião como se fosse um jornalista, esse é o modo correto de resposta né? devo remover coisas do tipo "ótima pergunta?", "a dica é:" ?

Comment: Injeção de dependências não é a mesma coisa que Inversão de dependência.

Answer (score 53):

**Injeção de Dependências** é um tipo de Inversão de Controle e significa que uma classe não mais é responsável por **criar ou buscar** os objetos dos quais depende.

Isso serve para desacoplar as classes, evitando dependência direta entre elas.

Os resultados são:

- Maior índice de reaproveitamento
- Permite incluir novas funcionalidades sem alterar as já existentes
- Possibilidade de criar *mocks* em testes unitários

## Exemplo

Vou ilustrar um caso simples de Injeção de Dependências sem necessidade de um *container* ou *framework*.

Suponha que você tem um sistema que processa pagamentos e implementa um método da seguinte forma:

```java
class Pagamento {

    void efetuarPagamento(String tipo, Integer codigo, Double valor) {
        if ("BOLETO".equals(tipo)) {
            new IntegracaoBoletoBanco().pagarBoleto(codigo, valor);
        } else if ("CARTAO".equals(tipo)) {
            new IntegracaoCartaoBanco().pagarCartao(codigo, valor);
        } else if ("DINHEIRO".equals(tipo)) {
            new IntegracaoContaBanco().pagarDinheiro(codigo, valor);
        }
    }

}
```

Note que o método instancia diretamente várias classes. Isso é muito ruim porque o código fica todo acoplado e é necessário realizar manutenção sempre que alguma implementação mudar.

Podemos refatorar esse código de forma que o algoritmo fique mais genérico. Vejamos:

```java
class Pagamento {

    IntegracaoBanco integracaoBanco;

    public Pagamento(IntegracaoBanco integracaoBanco) {
        this.integracaoBanco = integracaoBanco;
    }

    void efetuarPagamento(Integer codigo, Double valor) {
        integracaoBanco.pagar(codigo, valor);
    }

}
```

Aqui, `IntegracaoBanco` é uma interface e pode receber várias implementações. Além disso, classe agora exige que uma dessas implementações seja passada no construtor.

Nossa classe não tem mais a responsabilidade de conhecer as implementações de `IntegracaoBanco`. Quem vai chamá-la é quem deve passar a instância correta, injetando essa dependência no momento da criação da classe.

Dessa vez nosso código ficou muito mais simples e permite você criar novas implementações de pagamento através da interface ou estender as classes que já fazem parte do sistema sem mexer no código existente.

## Referências

Veja mais exemplos que envolvem Inversão de Controle nas minhas respostas aqui no SOPT:

- [Princípio aberto/fechado - como entender isso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15651/227)
- [Como efetuar TDD na camada Service](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19028/227)

Comment: fique com dúvida: **Posso dizer que injeção de dependência é somente transferir a responsabilidade da classe pra quem está instanciando ela?** No seu exemplo onde estaria o método que defini qual a forma de pagamento?

Comment: @Marconi Basicamente sim. Mais genericamente, consiste em externalizar a responsabilidade de instanciação. Pode ser para quem chama ou para um gerenciador central, tal como um framework de injeção de dependências. A ideia é que quem chama chama o pagamento sabe o tipo e pode passar a instância correta.  Note que este é um exemplo muito simplista e obviamente uma classe real vai ter mais lógica que justifique a existência de uma nova classe.

Comment: @utluiz, muito boa sua explicação é simples e objetiva.

Answer (score 35):

[Esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638919/how-to-explain-dependency-injection-to-a-5-year-old) resposta do SOEN merece ser traduzida e deixada aqui como referência:

Como explicar injecção de dependências a um garoto de 5 anos?

> Quando vai ao frigorífico (geladeira, em pt_BR) buscar qualquer coisa para si, pode causar problemas. Pode deixar a porta aberta, pode pegar qualquer coisa que o Pai ou a Mãe não querem que você coma. Pode até procurar qualquer coisa que não temos ou então encontrar uma coisa cujo o prazo de validade expirou.
>
> O que deve fazer é dizer o que precisa, "Eu preciso de qualquer coisa para beber ao lanche", e ai então eu certifico-me que você recebe o que precisa quando for lanchar.

Edit:

Um exemplo simples de injecção de dependência.

Sem injecção de dependência:

```
public void Test()
{
  Logger newLogger = new Logger(...);
  newLogger.Debug("");
}
```

Assumindo que a classe Logger implementa a interface ILogger, pode injectar o Logger da seguinte forma:

```
public void Test(ILogger logger)
{
  logger.Debug("");
}
```

Desta forma, a responsabilidade e o conhecimento de como instanciar a classe Logger ficou para o código que chamar o método Test.

Comment: show..mas a tradução melhor para o pt-br seria Geladeira e não Frigorífico...rs
Mas a resposta é boa..rs

Comment: @Dorathoto PT-PT não reconhece a palavra geladeira eheh

Answer (score 8):

Segundo artigo, o qual tive a audácia de traduzi-lo, escrito por Steve Smith e Scott Addie em 10/02/2017 para a Microsoft...

Injeção de dependência é uma técnica para livrar ou remover o acoplamento entre os objetos e seus colaboradores, ou dependentes. Em vez de instanciar objetos colaboradores diretamente, ou usar referências estáticas; esses colaboradores são fornecidos para a classe dependente de um modo particular. Geralmente, essas classes vão declarar suas dependências através de seus construtores, seguindo, assim, o Princípio das Dependências Explícitas. Esta forma de realizar uma injeção de dependência é conhecida como "Injeção por Construtor".

Quando as classes são desenvolvidas, levando em consideração a injeção de dependência, elas são menos acopladas, isso porque não há código as referenciando diretamente em seus dependentes. Essa forma segue o "Princípio da Inversão de Dependência", que prega o seguinte: "módulos de alto nível não devem depender de módulos de baixo nível; ambos devem depender de abstrações". Em vez de referenciar uma implementação específica, as classes dependentes devem requisitar abstrações (geralmente Interfaces), que lhes são fornecidas no momento de criação da classe. A extração de dependentes para dentro das interfaces e o fornecimento de implementações dessas interfaces como parâmetros também são exemplo do Padrão de Desenvolvimento Estratégia.

Quando um sistema é desenvolvido para usar Injeção de Dependência com muitas requisições de dependências via construtor (ou propriedades), é útil ter uma classe dedicada para criar essas classes juntamente com suas dependências associadas. Estas classes são referenciadas como repositórios, ou mais especificamente, repositórios de "Inversão de Controle (IoC)" ou repositórios de Injeção de Dependência (DI)". Um repositório é essencialmente uma fábrica que é responsável por fornecer instâncias de tipos que lhes são requisitados. Se um tipo específico declarou que possui dependências, e o repositório foi configurado para fornecer as dependência do tipo, ele criará as dependências como parte da requisição de criação da instância. Desta maneira, uma cadeia de dependência complexa pode ser fornecida para classe sem que nenhum código fixo seja inserido em seu construtor. Além de criar objetos com suas dependências, repositórios geralmente gerenciam o ciclo de vida do objeto na aplicação.

ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection (Acessado em 21/09/2017).