# Quais as diferenças entre Injeção de Dependência e Inversão de Controle?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, injeção-de-dependência

Às vezes parece que estamos falamos da mesma coisa (claro, não é) quando estes conceitos estão sendo utilizados. Qual é a real diferença entre eles? Quando utilizar um ou outro?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Inversão de Controle (ou IoC, Inversion of Control) é um termo mais amplo para se referir a um comportamento (explicado abaixo). Várias são as maneiras de implementar a inversão de controle.

Injeção de Dependência já não é algo tão amplo, é na verdade considerada até um padrão de projeto.

Injeção de Dependência é uma das formas de se fazer a Inversão de Controle. Então *"Quando utilizar um **ou** outro"* não faz muito sentido.

Mas a confusão é muito comum, não é raro encontrar os termos sendo utilizados indistintamente.

Acredito que explicando *um* e depois *o outro* desmistifique essa confusão.

## Inversão de Controle (IoC)

Inversão de controle é um comportamento presente quando utilizamos alguns frameworks. **Basicamente a idéia é separar *o quê* de *quando*.**

Seguem dois exemplos (código abstrato), a forma usual e a com IoC.

**Forma usual**

```
perguntarNome()
lerEntrada()
perguntarIdade()
lerEntrada()
SE verificarSeDadosEstaoValidos()
ENTAO cadastrar()
SENAO exibirMensagemDeErro()
```

**Com IoC**

```
quandoPerguntarNome(lerEntrada)
quandoPerguntarIdade(lerEntrada)
paraVerificarValidade(verificarSeDadosEstaoValidos)
paraCadastrar(cadastrar)
quandoHouverErro(exibirMensagemDeErro)
```

No segundo exemplo desatrelamos o quê será feito com o momento em que será feito; separamos as implementações do fluxo. Dessa maneira fica mais fácil reutilizar ou alterar apenas alguma parte do código (sem que tenha que se modificar/entender *o todo*).

Repare que existe brecha para encaixarmos diversos conceitos de programação, como princípios de orientação a objeto, desenho orientado a eventos, dentre outras coisas.

Pararei por aqui; isto é em sua essência o que chamamos de *Inversão de Controle*.

## Injeção de Dependência

Injeção de Dependência é uma das formas de se realizar a Inversão de Controle.

A técnica consiste em passar a dependência (o serviço) para o dependente (o cliente). Isso é a chamada injeção. **O importante é entender que *injetamos* o serviço no cliente, ao invés de o próprio cliente *procurar* e *construir* o serviço que irá utilizar.**

Acho que nada melhor que um exemplo prático para entender esse conceito. Segue abaixo um (simplificado) exemplo real que já cheguei a implementar em um dos sistemas em que trabalhei (código em C#):

```cs
public interface ILogger
{
    void Logar(string mensagem);
}

public class LogEmArquivo : ILogger
{
    void Logar(string mensagem)
    {
        // Loga a mensagem em um arquivo de log
    }
}

public class LogPorEmail : ILogger
{
    void Logar(string mensagem)
    {
        // Envia a mensagem por email aos responsáveis
    }
}

public class Principal
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public Principal(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    // Chamado pelos métodos internos da classe Principal
    // quando há necessidade de logar alguma informação
    private void LogarInformacao(string informacao)
    {
        _logger.Logar(informacao);
    }
}
```

A classe `Principal` necessita de um `ILogger` para funcionar, mas ela não "enxerga" ou constrói a implementação que ela irá utilizar, isso fica a cargo de quem irá construir a classe `Principal`. Dessa maneira fica desacoplada a implementação da ação de log com o que quer que seja que a classe principal irá fazer.

Como disse, esse é um exemplo real que cheguei a utilizar. No meu caso, a aplicação possuía no arquivo de configuração uma diretiva indicando qual o ambiente em que ela estava sendo executada (Desenvolvimento, Testes, Homologação, Produção...). Ao iniciar, a aplicação verificava qual o ambiente e, conforme essa configuração, utiliza um *logger* diferente para cada ambiente. Basicamente em *Desenvolvimento* e *Testes* utilizávamos apenas um log em arquivo, enquanto em *Homologação* e *Produção* utilizámos envio de email (onde os problemas eram mais sérios).

Em tempo de execução, programaticamente, a aplicação trocava sua implementação de logger a ser utilizada. Essa é uma das vantagens de ser ter o código desacoplado.

---

## Leitura

Um dos precursores a discutir o tema é o autor Martin Fowler. Para quem deseja aprofundar no tema convém ler os artigos sobre o assunto em seu blog:

- [InversionOfControl](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html)
- [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

Comment: Pesquisando sobre um comentário de um autor que diz haver outros tipos de IoC além de DI, acabei ficando mais curioso sobre o tema, pois até os meus estudos atuais, só conheço o DI mesmo, porém no artigo [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern - Forms of Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection) Martin Fowler cita apenas que há 3 formas de DI, além disso não achei outros tipos de IoC.

Answer (score 42):

## [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

IoC pode até não ser tão criado em projetos comuns, porém ele é muito usado em grande parte das aplicações. IoC é também o [Princípio de Hollywood](https://wiki.c2.com/?HollywoodPrinciple), onde os produtores falam para os atores "não nos chame, nós chamaremos você". Isto significa que **um componente/*framework* toma o controle da aplicação e quando ele precisar da sua intervenção ele chama o que você terá que providenciar**. O caso mais comum é um [*event loop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) presentes em praticamente todos os mecanismos de jogos e gerenciadores de janelas do mercado. Alguns ERPs também funcionam assim, eles tomam conta de todo o processo e chamam as partes que os "usuários" podem personalizar o funcionamento.

[*Framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) é importante aqui, já que IoC é a base de *frameworks*.

## [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Injeção de dependência é apenas uma das formas de se aplicar o IoC. Já vi inúmeras definições formais mas o conceito é extremamente simples. Você está fazendo DI quando retira as dependências existentes em uma parte do programa, possivelmente uma classe. Ela facilita o desacoplamento.

A melhor definição de DI é **permitir que estados e comportamentos sejam determinados através de passagem de parâmetros**. Ou seja, é permitir que você se referencie a uma classe ainda não conhecida durante o desenvolvimento da classe atual. Você elimina a dependência de uma classe específica. Isto pode ser feito através de parâmetros nos construtores, métodos comuns ou em propriedades da classe atual.

## Vantagens e desvantagens

Convenhamos que isto é uma enorme facilidade. Serve para **flexibilizar a aplicação**, inclusive para testá-la já que o teste normalmente precisa ser feito com premissas simuladas. É possível assim criar sistemas de *plugins*, configurações, mudanças de execução *on-the-fly*, permite a clara separação de responsabilidades, limpando o código e facilitando o desenvolvimento e manutenção, e permite o [desacoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) das classes.

Mas há quem diga que o desacoplamento total pode trazer outro problema. Você deixa a responsabilidade para o usuário. Eu sou uma destas pessoas que preferem o pragmatismo do que o academicismo. Claro que você pode ter algum caso que este total desacoplamento é realmente importante, mas na maior parte das vezes você só quer a flexibilidade. Então minha postura é criar sim o parâmetro, mas também providenciar uma dependência padrão. Assim o consumidor desta classe (ou função, ou componente) não precisa se preocupar em criar e passar nada como parâmetro quando o que se deseja é fazer exatamente o que aquela parte da aplicação sabe que é apropriado e provavelmente desejado.

A única "desvantagem" disto é que cria uma dependência para a implementação padrão. Mas por que isto é ruim? Eu acho que se fosse ruim nem existiriam *frameworks*. A flexibilidade é vantagem, a total independência é teoria barata. Você vai prover uma implementação para uma *string* como parâmetro de tudo que precise de uma *string*? Tudo tem limite. A diferença entre remédio e veneno é a dosagem.

Obviamente que separar as responsabilidades também significa espalhar as partes pela aplicação, o que dificulta o seu entendimento e eventualmente a manutenção. Legibilidade também tem a ver com organização. Ter as partes espalhadas torna a leitura mais difícil. Especialmente porque você passar ter muitos tipos só para cumprir a injeção e requer o planejamento muito maior do que se está fazendo (que alguns vão considerar vantagem e outros, desvantagem).

Vou exemplificar com o que o talles já fez na resposta dele:

```cs
public interface ILogger {
    void Logar(string mensagem);
}

public class LogEmArquivo : ILogger {
    void Logar(string mensagem) {
        //Loga a mensagem em um arquivo de log
    }
}

public class LogPorEmail : ILogger {
    void Logar(string mensagem) {
        //Envia a mensagem por email aos responsáveis
    }
}

public class Principal {
    private ILogger _logger;
    public Principal(ILogger logger) {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public Principal() {
        _logger = new LogPorArquivo();
    }
    //Chamando métodos privados da classe Principal quando precisa logar alguma informação
    private void LogarInformacao(string informacao) {
        _logger.Logar(informacao);
    }
}

public static Aplicacao {
    public static void Main() {
        var logArq = new Principal(); //exemplo de uso
        var logMail = new Principal(new LogPorEmail()); //exemplo injetando a dependência
    }
}
```

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

O uso destes recursos deve servir a aplicação e não a interesses externos como a necessidade de testes, por exemplo. Quando precisa testar, use um [padrão de projeto adequado para testes](http://deliberate-software.com/simplemock-unit-test-mocking/). Testes podem ser obtidos com boas ferramentas, não com o jeito que se cria código. Organizar o código de um jeito só porque facilita o teste é algo errado, IMHO. Fazer porque facilita a manutenção e por acaso facilita o teste é ok. Se a ferramenta de testes que usa exige uma codificação específica, troque de ferramenta.

Lembrando que devemos sempre [programar para a interface e não para a implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).