# Quais são os Tipos de IoC?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, ioc

Lendo o Livro "**Pro Spring Security**" de Carlo Scarioni da Editora Apress, edição 2013, me deparei com o seguinte texto que me deixou confuso sobre IoC:

> The basic idea of DI, ***a type of Inversion of Control (IoC)***, is simply that instead of having an object instantiate its needed dependencies, the dependencies are somehow given to the object. In a polymorphic way, the objects that are given as dependencies to the target object that depends on them are known to this target object just by an abstraction (like an interface in Java) and not by the exact implementation of the dependency.

Ou seja DI é um tipo de **Inversão de Controle** (IoC), porém nenhum outro padrão de projeto que se caracterize como IoC, ao pesquisar achei este artigo ([Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern - Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection)) do Martin Fowler que explica, porém leva a outro entendimento (o que acho correto):

> ***There are three main styles*** of dependency injection. The names I'm using for them are **Constructor Injection**, **Setter Injection**, and **Interface Injection**. ...

Bem Martin Fowler diz haver tres estilos (styles), não tipos, e são todos **Dependency Injection**, então quais são os outros tipos de IoC? ou seria um erro da edição em questão/autor do livro citado?

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais as diferenças entre Injeção de Dependência e Inversão de Controle?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/91)

Comment: Neste mesmo artigo do Fowler que você referenciou ele explica uma alternativa à injeção de dependência na implementação da inversão de controle: o pattern **Service Locator**. Não existem *"tipos"* de IoC, mas sim *design patterns* para implementá-lo. Além da injeção de dependência e do service locator, eu já vi também o uso simples de arquivos de configuração, o qual determina qual serviço deve ser utilizado quando o código onde o controle for invertido precisar daquele tipo de serviço em particular.

Comment: Outras formas de implementação de IoC que tenho visto: orientação a eventos, *observer*, *plug-ins* ou *add-ins*, *convention over configuration* (em que o código onde o controle foi invertido sabe qual serviço instanciar e utilizar baseado num padrão de nomes para o serviço), *anotations* (Java) ou *attributes* (C#)... Devo ter visto mais mas não me ocorre agora.

Comment: @Caffé, seria mais adequado postar seu comentário como resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem quatro maneiras de se implementar Dependency Injection:

- Construtor: Modo em que implementamos a injeção de dependência na    definição dos construtores das classes;
- Getter and Setter: Modo em que implementamos a injeção de dependência    na definição dos Gets e Sets das classes;
- Interface Implementation: Modo em que se usa a definição de    Interfaces para realizar a injeção de dependência;
- Service Locator: Modo em que construímos classes que servem como    "localizadores" de objetos que iremos instanciar em nossas outras    classes.

Fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/design-patterns-injecao-de-dependencia-com-c/23671

Answer (score 1):

Os tipos que você se refere, são as 3 formas de se implementar a inversão de controle, que são:

- Padrão Factory
- Padrão Service Locator
- Injeção de Dependência