# O que é Service Container?

Tags: php, laravel

Estava lendo a respeito de [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container) no Laravel, porém, não consegui compreender muito bem a finalidade deste recurso.

Eu sei que para criar novos serviços temos que usar alguns métodos do Laravel:

```
App::bind()
```

ou

```
App::instance()
```

existe outros.

## Perguntas

1. O que é Service Container?
2. Quando eu devo utilizar este recurso?
3. Quais vantagens ele pode trazer para minha aplicação web?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> O que é Service Container?

Container de Servico. É um mecanismo criado pelo Laravel que facilita o gerenciamento de dependências entre classe. Esse assunto está ligado diretamente à Injeção de Dependência - *Dependency Injection*.

O Service Container tem como finalidade automatizar/facilitar o processo de resolução de dependências entre as classes, uma vez que ele armazena a instância ou a definição de como determinada classe deverá ser instanciada. Assim, em cada definição de um serviço, tem-se o conhecimento da dependência que deverá ser usada pra ele.

**Nota:** não é algo exclusivo do Laravel o termo *Service Container*. Creio que o [Symfony já adotava essa ideia](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) antes do próprio Laravel.

**Mas o que é uma dependência?**

Primeiro quero explicar esse ponto: A dependência estão em classes que dependem de instâncias de outras. Essa "dependência" geralmente está definida no construtor ou em setters.

Um exemplo básico onde A depende de B que depende de C:

```
 class A {

    protected $b;

    public function __construct(B $b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    public function fazAlgumaCoisaComB()
    {
         $this->b->blah();
    }
 }

 class B{
      protected $c;

      public function __construct(C $c) {
           $this->c = $c;
      }

}
```

Nesse pequeno exemplo, vemos que pra criar a instância de `A`, é necessário ter uma instância de `B`, que também depende de `C`.

No caso do Service Container, geralmente você define um nome para o serviço e atribui a uma instância da classe (geralmente em casos de Singleton) ou amarra a criação do mesmo dentro de uma função anônima.

Por exemplos:

```
 $this->app->bind('C', function ($app) {
      return new C;
 });

 $this->app->bind('B', function($app)
 {
      return new B($app[C::class]); // ou $app['C']
 });
```

No caso acima, ao chamar `App::make('B')` ou `$app['B']`, você estará criando uma instância de `B`. Mas note que, ao invés de ter que definir a todo momento qual é a instância de `C` que será usada em `B`, o processo foi feito automaticamente. Ou seja, você não precisou ficar repetindo o processo de definição da dependência de `C`.

> Quando eu devo utilizar este recurso?

Creio que a melhor forma de utilizá-lo é quando se tornaria trabalhoso toda vez que for usar um objeto ter que instanciá-lo manualmente e ir construindo as demais dependências.

Por exemplo, seria mais viável você utilizar uma instância de `C` no primeiro exemplo abaixo.

Exemplo 1:

```
    app('A')->fazAlgumaCoisaComB()
```

Exemplo 2:

```
   $a = new A(new B(new C));

   $a->fazAgumaCoisaComB();
```

O exemplo acima é simples, mas imagina em classes complexas, cuja a instância é trabalhosa de se obter, se você fosse fazer como no segundo exemplo!

Além disso, com o mecanismo inteligente do Laravel de injetar as dependências automaticamente através do Tipo do parâmetro, torna-se uma vantagem ainda maior usar o Service Container:

Exemplo:

```
 function getIndex(B $c, C $c) {
     // As injeções serão feitas automaticamente por causa 
     // do service container registrado para eles
 }
```

<sub>O exemplo acima me lembro um pouco o AngularJS s2</sub>

Outra vantagem é que, se você mudar alguma dependência de alguma classe sua, precisará mudar o código em um lugar só. Se fizer manualmente, terá que mudar todos os lugares onde definiu a instância do objeto que possui a dependência.

> Quais vantagens ele pode trazer para minha aplicação web?

Quando a isso, não creio que o impacto seja algo visível para o usuário final. Trata-se de algo que vai auxiliar o desenvolvedor a gastar menos tempo com repetições e definição de dependências ao longo de um projeto.

Eu fiz uma pergunta similar aqui no site, que poderá ajudar esclarecer algumas dúvidas:

[Quais são os padrões de projeto referentes a ServiceProvider e ServiceContainer, usados no Laravel e Symfony?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116120/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-padr%C3%B5es-de-projeto-referentes-a-serviceprovider-e-servicecontainer)

Importantes leituras:

- [Quais são os Tipos de IoC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73160/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-tipos-de-ioc)