# Será que qualquer projeto pode ser adequado aos princípios pregados pelo SOLID? Quais os passos para isso?

Tags: php, design-pattern, solid

Estou tentando adequar um dos meus projetos aos padrões do ***SOLID***, porém, não estou conseguindo sair do *marco zero*. O projeto em questão pode ser encontrado em: https://github.com/crphp/webservice

Após algumas tentativas surgiram as seguintes dúvidas:

- Todo projeto é passivo de adequação a todos os 5 princípios preconizados pelos padrões do SOLID?
- Estes princípios possuem alguma dependência hierárquica de implementação?
- Acredito que o princípio **SRP** possa ser considerado um ponto de partida, mas e depois, qual seria o próximo principio a ser atendido, existe uma ordem lógica *(não obrigatória em si, mas sim lógica)*?
- Em uma de minhas investidas, tentei atender ao princípio **ISP**, entretanto, não consegui determinar **interfaces + assinatura comum**. Até cheguei a uma interface comum, entretanto a assinatura dessa interface divergia entre as classes do projeto (**Crphp\src\Soap.php** e **Crphp\src\ClienteGenerico.php**). O que fazer nestes casos? Será que um projeto (módulo) tão pequeno requer a criação de mais de uma interface para tentar transpor essa barreira?

> Os 5 princípio mencionados acima são:
>
> - **SRP** - Single responsibility principle
> - **OCP** - Open/closed principle
> - **LSP** - Liskov substitution principle
> - **ISP** - Interface segregation principle
> - **DIP** - Dependency inversion principle
>
> Fonte: [https://medium.com/thiago-aragao/solid-princ%C3%ADpios-da-programação-orientada-a-objetos-ba7e31d8fb25](https://medium.com/thiago-aragao/solid-princ%C3%ADpios-da-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-a-objetos-ba7e31d8fb25)

Comment: E por que quer "adequear"  seus projetos ao SOLID?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é SRP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100516/o-que-%C3%A9-e-como-se-usa-o-srp)

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais as diferenças entre Injeção de Dependência e Inversão de Controle?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21319)

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais são os tipos de IoC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73160/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-tipos-de-ioc)

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é Dependency Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20770/o-que-%C3%A9-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia)

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é DIP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101552/o-que-%C3%A9-princ%C3%ADpio-da-invers%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia-dip)

Comment: Tem material aí pra estudar um dia inteiro, kkkkkk

Answer (score 2):

Não existe um sequencia para "adequar" um projeto ao SOLID!

O acrônimo diz repeito a princípios de desenvolvimento que devem, sempre que possível, ser seguidos para evitar problemas no software com o passar do tempo, principalmente se você trabalhar em equipe.

Haverá momentos em que será necessário não seguir algum princípio. Desde que essa decisão seja tomada com consciência do que se está fazendo, não há problema algum. O importante é saber o porquê do SOLID.

O SOLID existe para ajudar os desenvolvedores a corrigir uma série de problemas que podem acontecer dentro da Orientação a Objetos. No paper do Robert Martin, responsável pela difusão dos princípios ([Design Principles and Design Patterns](http://www.cvc.uab.es/shared/teach/a21291/temes/object_oriented_design/materials_adicionals/principles_and_patterns.pdf)), é falado muito sobre mudanças e refatoração, uma característica importantíssima para qualquer software passível de evolução.

Sistemas muito rígidos (resistentes à mudanças) dão muito trabalho na hora de evoluir. O contrário também é preocupante, em sistemas muito frágeis a simples alteração de uma parte pode quebrar outras dez em todo o sistema.

Os princípios SOLID objetivam tornar o software mais manutenível e fácil de entender. Em outras palavras, o SOLID tornará o software:

- Mais organizado;
- Aberto para receber melhorias;
- Evolutivo: ao ser atualizado não terá efeitos colaterais indesejados;
- Fácil de ser testado;
- Menos propenso a repetição de código;
- Fácil de ter seus módulos reaproveitados.

O contrário também deve ser considerado, ou seja, sistemas onde os princípios SOLID não são observados tendem a:

- Possuir código sem padrão, desorganizado e macarrônico;
- Possuir classes inchadas, com explosão de métodos e difíceis de entender;
- Ser muito rígidos em algumas partes, dificultando as mudanças;
- Ser muito frágeis, quebrando outras partes do sistema com facilidade;
- Ter muito código repetido ao longo do sistema;
- Ser muito difíceis de testar.

O assunto é vasto e muito interessante. Para mais informações, sugiro que leia [Os princípios SOLID](https://medium.com/contexto-delimitado/os-princ%C3%ADpios-solid-34b136f507bb).