# Composição e Injeção de Dependência

Tags: php, design-pattern

Estava estudando Design Patterns e me veio uma pergunta: O conceito Composição (OOP), inflige no padrão "Injeção de Dependência"?

Comment: Tem alguma coisa específica que deseja saber? Tem algum exemplo? Pode ser que sim, pode ser que não. Depende de como usa.

Comment: Não, na verdade foi uma duvida que me surgiu durante os estudos

Comment: O PHP é mais uma das linguagens mais flexíveis, é permitido fazer a Injeção de Dependência.

Comment: Pode explicar o que quer dizer com "inflige no padrão"?

Comment: Talvez ajude, [Quais as diferenças entre Injeção de Dependência e Inversão de Controle?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/91)