# O que é que permite um método ser interceptado em C#?

Tags: c#, .net

A intercepção de um método é uma técnica que pode ser usada para executar um excerto de código antes de executar uma acção principal. Ou seja, duma forma muito simplificada este também seria um exemplo de intercepção:

```
public void A(){ 
    Console.Writeline("Estou a interceptar B!");
    B(); 
}
private void B(){
    Console.Writeline("Eu sou a acção principal B");
}
```

A diferença é que normalmente, quando a técnica de intercepção é usada o método A não tem conhecimento do método B. Na verdade o método A pode ser eventualmente ser usado para interceptar qualquer método existente de uma ou mais classes.

Esta técnica pode ser usada por exemplo para fazer logging de entrada do método, metendo no log informação do nome e dos parâmetros do método que vai ser chamado.

Eu já usei bibliotecas como [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/) que facilitam o uso de interceptadores. Mas o que quero perguntar aqui é: **Como é que eles funcionam?** Ou seja como é que é possível eles chamarem a função A antes da B se ela não conhece B. Um exemplo de como um interceptador básico poderia ser feito, sem recorrer a nenhuma biblioteca seria bem vindo.

Comment: Vinculada: [Quais as diferenças entre Injeção de Dependência e Inversão de Controle?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/18246)

Comment: Olá. Você também pode utilizar o MEF (Microsoft Extensibility Framework) que é nativo do .NET, e assim como o Castle Windsor permitirá que você faça a Injeção de Dependência, desacoplando assim O Chamador das bibliotecas e funções que serão chamadas. Favor verificar: http://www.devmedia.com.br/extensibilidade-com-mef/19151

Comment: Olhe a resposta do Aeronaught: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592787/what-really-interceptors-do-with-my-c-sharp-class. Um outro artigo sobre: http://www.progware.org/blog/post/interception-and-interceptors-in-c-(aspect-oriented-programming).aspx Obs. estou copiando os links pois é muito conteúdo para ficar traduzindo e não tenho como replicar as ilustrações do segundo link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você menciona o [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor), que é para injeção de dependência, mas o teor da sua pergunta está relacionada mesmo é ao [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy), que como o nome sugere é para a criação de **proxies dinâmicos**.

O código que você escreveu também não poderia ser chamado de "intercepção" nem mesmo "simplificada", uma vez que o consumidor está a consumir diretamente *A* e a rigor nem sabe que *B* será invocado.

Intercepção seria o consumir invocar *B* e o código de *A* ser invocado de maneira transparente, sem que *B* tenha sido programado pra isso e sem que o próprio consumidor tenha conhecimento disso.

## Como funciona o proxy dinâmico (*dynamic proxy*)

Basicamente, o *Castle DynamicProxy* cria uma classe que **herda** da classe para a qual ele vai servir de proxy e sobrescreve os membros desta classe.

O consumidor da classe original não cria uma instância dela diretamente; ao invés disso ele pede a instância ao Castle, e o Castle entrega uma instância da classe herdada que ele criou automaticamente, mais ou menos assim (pseudo código):

```
ClasseA objeto = Castle.CrieInstancia<ClasseA>(ClasseInterceptadora);
```

Então a variável *objeto* contém uma instância não de *ClasseA* mas sim de algo tipo *"ClasseA$Proxy12349876"*, que é a herança de *ClasseA* criada automaticamente pelo Castle.

Agora, para cada método invocado em *objeto*, a instância de *"ClasseA$Proxy12349876"* vai tratar de invocar, antes e depois, o código que você escreveu na *ClasseInterceptadora*.

**Importante** observar que como o Castle vai criar uma **herança** da sua classe, só será possível substituir os membros **virtuais** dela.

## Utilidade de um proxy dinâmico (um exemplo)

Quando você usa o [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info), você declara entidades (grosseiramente falando, classes que representarão registros do banco de dados).

Um entidade pode referenciar outra, mais ou menos assim (pseudo código):

```
class Funcionario {
    long id;
    string nome;
    Departamento departamento;
}

class Departamento {
    long id;
    string nome;
    string centroDeCusto;
}
```

Quando você recuperar um funcionário do banco de dados, o NHibernate não vai te entregar uma instância de *Funcionário*, mas sim uma instância de uma classe que ele criou herdando de *Funcionário*. Esta herança que o NHibernate cria usando o Castle vai atuar como um **proxy** para a classe *Funcionário*.

Então, se o carregamento da entidade relacionada estiver configurado como [lazy load](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html), quando você fizer isso:

```
Funcionario funcionario = db.getFuncionarioDoMes();
long idDepartamento = funcionario.departamento.id;
```

*funcionario* conterá um proxy, o qual entregará também um proxy em *funcionario.departamento*. Então, a instância de proxy existente em *funcionario.departamento* conterá apenas o id em memória, e vai te entregar sem precisar buscar no banco de dados todas as informações do departamento. Agora, se você fizer isso:

```
string nomeDepartamento = funcionario.departamento.nome;
```

então a instância de proxy existente em *funcionario.departamento* fará uma consulta no banco de dados, buscando todas as informações do departamento para disponibilizá-la pra você.

Neste exemplo, foi interessante o uso de um *proxy* para que você não precisasse codificar na sua entidade toda esta complexidade tecnológica.

## Como fazer um proxy (um "interceptador") sem recorrer a uma biblioteca

O proxy criado pelo Castle para interceptar o consumo de *funcionario.departamento* no exemplo acima é um *design pattern*.

Este *design pattern* pode ser implementado facilmente em C# sem precisar recorrer a nenhuma biblioteca externa. Veja este exemplo retirado da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern):

```
interface ICar
{
    void DriveCar();
}

// Real Object
public class Car : ICar
{
    public void DriveCar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("O carro foi dirigido!");
    }
}

//Proxy Object
public class ProxyCar : ICar
{
    private Driver driver;
    private ICar realCar;

    public ProxyCar(Driver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.realCar = new Car();
    }

    public void DriveCar()
    {
        if (driver.Age < 18)
            Console.WriteLine("Desculpe, o motorista é muito jovem para dirigir.");
        else
            this.realCar.DriveCar();
     }
}

public class Driver
{
    private int Age { get; set; }

    public Driver(int age)
    {
        this.Age = age;
    }
}

// Como usar o proxy
private void btnProxy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ICar car = new ProxyCar(new Driver(16));
    car.DriveCar();

    car = new ProxyCar(new Driver(25));
    car.DriveCar();
}
```

E existem diversas outras maneiras de se implementar um proxy.

O que o Castle faz de especial, e isso o C# não tem nada nativo que faça de maneira tão completa e simplificada, é criar o proxy **dinamicamente** sem que a classe interceptada pelo proxy e nem o consumidor precisem ter ciência de que há um proxy ali (não há necessidade de que a classe interceptada implemente uma certa interface, por exemplo, e nem é necessário escrever um proxy exclusivo para cada classe que vá ser interceptada).

A única coisa que você precisa fazer em função do proxy do Castle é garantir que os métodos que vão ser interceptados pelo proxy sejam virtuais.

Comment: Acredito que usar o `CodeDOM` para criar os proxys dinamicamente é uma alternativa interessante :)