# Qual a diferença entre DI, factories e locators?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, injeção-de-dependência

Já [perguntei sobre injeção de dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101). Ele é muito usada. Na minha opinião é até abusada.

Mas vi que no lugar dela pode-se usar *factories* ou *locators*. O que seriam eles, quais as vantagens e desvantagens de usar cada um?

Comment: atualizei minha resposta para mencionar o `dagger`, que tem um comportamento diferente do que o que citei como normal para injeção de dependência

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Injeção de dependência* e *service locator* (estou assumindo que com *locator* você quis dizer [Service Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)) são maneiras de se realizar a inversão de dependência. *Factories*, por sua vez, se preocupam em instanciar objetos sem que seu chamador se preocupe com seus detalhes de instanciamento (http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).

## Dependências e inversão de controle

Ao usar inversão de dependência, se você souber qual o objeto chamado em *bootstrap time* (mais nesse tópico em parágrafos mais a frente), então você não precisa se preocupar em delongar até o último momento para usar a dependência. Nesses casos, a injeção de dependência vai tornar seu trabalho muito fácil. Um exemplo de onde se pode usar uma injeção de dependência é em usos especiais de [*multitons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) ou mesmo [*singletons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), que se conhece a priori/estaticamente qual a necessidade.

Teve um projeto grande que eu trabalhei de unificação de código. Na empresa, existiam dois produtos que deveriam fazer a mesma coisa, um *webapp* em [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) (com [*iBatis*](http://ibatis.apache.org/) gerenciando acesso ao banco) e uma aplicação *mobile* em [TotalCross](http://www.totalcross.com/). Devido à incompatibilidades entre os recursos de banco TotalCross e JDBC, e também que existem API Java que o *iBatis* usava que não existem no TotalCross, não havia como compartilhar código que fazia o resgate de informações nem o que fazia a persistência. Então, a solução foi ter uma interface cujas implementações acessariam o banco e deixar o ambiente que subia a aplicação inserir a classe apropriada. No *webapp*, o Spring tomou conta disso usando as interfaces `@Component` e `@Autowired`. No TotalCross, era mais rápido fazer a injeção na mão usando uma classe para realizar o *bootstrap* da aplicação.

Sobre o ciclo de vida da aplicação, eu mencionei o *bootstrap time*. Normalmente não é o termo mais comum, mas eu precisei diferenciar o tempo em que a aplicação está se preparando para subir do tempo em que ela realmente está ativamente rodando. Essa separação temporal se encontra muito, por exemplo, quando você está trabalhando na [Unity](https://unity3d.com/pt), em que você prepara a cena usando o [`MonoBehaviour.start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) para tratar de algumas conformações do ambiente que precisa ter antes de começar o jogo, porém que não é possível informar no tempo de construção do objeto/é mais prático resolver programaticamente do que no editor de cena; eu gosto de imaginar que o *bootstrap time* é análogo à montagem de um jogo de tabuleiro, como a distribuição de territórios e objetivos no [War](http://www.growgames.com.br/Jogos/War).

### Ambientes de uma aplicação

De modo geral, toda aplicação tem os seguintes ambientes:

1. *compile time*, em que o compilador consegue decidir com o que se está trabalhando; se você consegue prender o valor de uma variável em *compile time*, então significa que você como programador deve colocar os valores de modo imperativo;
2. *static code time*, no caso do Java, processamento de anotação acontece nesse ponto; de certo ponto de vista, é como uma continuação do *compile time*;
3. *bootstrap time*, esse é o tempo entre apertar o botão *run* e a aplicação estar de fato rodando, o tempo de *setup*; injeção de dependência do Spring via *XML* se encaixa aqui (também creio que a injeção via `@Autowired` também); normalmente é uma parte do *run time*, mas neste caso em específico creio que seja notório destacá-lo;
4. *run time*, o ambiente em que o código está realmente funcionando e a aplicação no ar; qualquer coisa que exclusivamente só pode ser decidida aqui é completamente dinâmica, vindo de fontes alheias ao código.

Um exemplo de *service locator* bem utilizado é no [SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), onde o programa não sabe (nem tem como saber) a priori em que SGBD vai se conectar, dependendo do serviço de conexões cadastradas no JDBC para conseguir realizar o contato com sucesso.

Injeção de dependência pode ocorrer também na criação de objetos (como no caso do [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html) tendo a dependência no construtor). Essa injeção pode ocorrer sob demanda, não necessariamente a priori. Neste caso, a injeção funciona como se estivesse no *bootstrap* do componente, antes dele estar em seu *run time* propriamente dito.

## *Factories*

*Factories* são objetos que criam objetos, então a inversão de dependência aqui ocorre em outro nível. Por exemplo, para criar conexões de *socket* para passar adiante para a classe que lida com conexões HTTP, de modo que quem fala HTTP não precise se preocupar em falar _socket_ês, precisa apenas que passem um construtor de *sockets* que faça isso. Vide [`SocketFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html) do Java, que faz exatamente isso.

O padrão de injeção de dependência pode ser usado de maneira a usar/precisar de *factories*.

## Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um deles?

De modo geral, eu sempre prefiro onde possível usar injeção de dependência, porque com ela eu deixo o fluxo do programa mais previsível. Sem falar que ela é fácil de aplicar tendo um framework que faça isso. Eu sempre ponho previsibilidade e facilidade como primeiras escolhas.

*Locators* são para quando você consegue consultar de um registro comum o que você precisa naquele momento. Eu acho particularmente feio, mas funcional. Também permite *hotswaps* para uma melhor performance ou estabilidade. Por exemplo, se tiver uma *thread* em paralelo checando se foi colocada uma biblioteca de processamento de imagem mais nova e trocando o retorno para a requisição de `leitor de JPG` para o mais novo desejado.

*Factories* normalmente são usadas para uma `delayed creation` do objeto, para ele de fato ser criado no ponto em que ele será usado.

---

## UPDATE: DAGGER

Recentemente, em uma requisição de um cliente no trabalho, tive acesso ao injetor de dependência `dagger`.

Eis aqui algumas fontes sobre o assunto:

- considerações e elucidações feitas pela equipe TotalCross (eu incluso): https://gitlab.com/totalcross/TotalCross/wikis/dagger
- página oficial: https://google.github.io/dagger/
- fonte: https://github.com/google/dagger

Basicamente, o `dagger` *escreve* o trabalho do *bootstrap time* em código Java, transformando as operações desse para o momento de *static code time*. A ideia do `dagger` é remover o peso extra devido ao modo de se gerar a injeção de dependência no `Spring` ou no `Guice`, transformando o trabalho que normalmente é feito por introspecção (o que normalmente é impossível em *compile time*) para uma análise que é feita em código estático (ou seja: durante a compilação).

Supostamente, o `dagger` tem como resultado final o mesmo que a injeção de dependência *feita à mão*, porém ele gerencia isso para você de uma maneira muito boa.