# Qual a diferença entre "compile time" e "run time"?

Tags: runtime

*Compile time* e *run time* são termos comuns que frequentemente ouvimos na área de programação, quais são as principais diferenças ou características destes dois termos?

Comment: Essa resposta trata disso superficialmente: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/197854/64969

Comment: Basicamente, compile time se refere aos eventos que ocorrem durante a compilação (ex: erros de sintaxe) enquanto run time são eventos que ocorrem quando a aplicação está sendo executada (ex: nullpointerexception).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

O [***compile time***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time) ou tempo de compilação é tudo o que ocorre durante o processo de compilação, tudo o que pode ser detectado, gerado, otimizado, realizado quando o código está sendo compilado. Em geral é onde se pega erros sintáticos, léxicos e semânticos, de tipagem ou até mesmo, em conjunto com outras ferramentas, validar com teste de unidade ou outras análises chamadas de estáticas.

Já [***run time***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_(program_lifecycle_phase)) ou tempo de execução é tudo o que ocorre quando o código já está executando, então ali se houver um problema pode ser tarde demais para solucionar. Por outro lado, pode ser que só naquele momento com o dado certo é possível entender o que ocorre, o que pode ser otimizado, etc. Erros dependentes do dado a ser processado costumam paralisar a execução se não houver um mecanismo que trate dele. Em geral entradas de dados diretas ou indiretas é que determinarão o que ocorrerá.

Para robustez e melhor performance costumamos dizer que é melhor resolver tudo o que dá em tempo de compilação, e é um dos motivos das linguagens interpretadas serem consideradas "inferiores" já que elas costumam ter só o tempo de execução. Mas há casos que justamente deixar para tempo de execução é a única ou melhor saída.

O termo [***link time***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_time) pode ser usado também para aquilo que será resolvido em tempo de [*linkedição*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101), mas é mais raro.

Algumas linguagens possuem o *link time* dinâmico, ou seja, logo antes do tempo de execução, e não logo depois da compilação. Algumas fazem de forma tão estruturada e complexa com um mecanismo específico que usamos o termo [***JIT time***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101).

Ainda existe o ***design time***, que tem um contexto um pouco diferente. Ele se refere ao momento que o código está sendo criado, ou seja, é antes da compilação e pode ter auxílio de alguma ferramenta.

Por último o termo *development time* ainda pode ser usado para todo o ciclo de desenvolvimento em contraponto ao ciclo de produção.

[Pode interessar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/332635/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

**Compile Time** - Tempo de compilação:

Durante a compilação se detecta problemas óbvios no código como erros de sintaxe.

**Run Time** - Tempo de execução:

Durante a execução também podem ocorrer erros. Estes podem ser causados por inputs inadequados que não passaram por nenhum tratamento ou outra ocorrência que não pôde ter sido detectada como erro pelo compilador. Exemplos: O programa espera um número e é digitado uma letra, ou o programa tenta usar uma variável que não foi iniciada e dá um NullPointerException, etc.