# Pra que serve a dupla exclamação antes da chamada do método no Kotlin?

Tags: operadores, kotlin

Estou estudando Kotlin. Percebi que, na conversão para o tipo `int`, é necessário colocar a dupla exclamação (`!!`).

Exemplo:

```
var input = readLine()!!.toInt();
```

Geralmente em outras linguagens usa-se dupla exclamação [para fazer cast de um valor para `boolean`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-javascript). Porém nesse caso, não parece tratar-se de cast, já que não se trata de uma operação booleana (como é o caso de checagem de condições).

Sendo assim, pra que serve essa dupla exclamação, que está antes de `toInt`, no Kotlin?

Comment: [!! Operador](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kotlin odeia erro de referência nula, uma das maiores críticas que se faz ao Java. Então por padrão não é possível criar código que tente acessar um nulo. Mas pode ser que deseja isto, provavelmente pra ter compatibilidade com algum código do Java, ou talvez porque lhe falte um parafuso :) É aí que entra este operador. Ele tenta acessar o valor da variável, mas se ela for nula lança uma `NullPointerException` como o Java faria. Ou seja, você está dizendo para o compilador ignorar o que normalmente ele faz de proibir o acesso em valor nulo e deixar a decisão do que fazer em [tempo de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216594/101).

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val texto: String? = null
    println(texto!!) //gerará uma exceção
    //seria o mesmo que println(texto ?: throw NullPointerException())
    //ou ainda println(texto != null ? texto : throw NullPointerException())
}
```

Veja ["funcionando" no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/ztzXhn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/urxduqww-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/OperatorNPE.kt).

Se tirar o `!!` o código nem compila, o que geralmente é o melhor a fazer mesmo.