# O que significa o ponto de exclamação após o nome de um tipo?

Tags: característica-linguagem, tipagem, kotlin

Tenho visto muito em Kotlin tipos marcados com um ponto de exclamação ao final. Principalmente quando uso API's do Java.

Algo como

```
CharSequence!
```

O que isso significa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indica que o tipo pode ser nulo. Em Kotlin os tipos não podem ser nulos por padrão. Mas em Java eles podem, pelos menos os tipos por referência. Então precisa ter um tipo que permita interoperar com essa condição do Java.

A linguagem precisa respeitar a decisão do Java e por isso para dar mais robustez ao seu próprio código e até ganhar performance é necessário informar para o compilador quando há uma exceção à regra da garantia de não nulo.

Não use se não for interoperar com Java. Na verdade em boa parte dos casos é melhor que tenha uma forma de garantir o tipo não nulo (alguma operação que verifique manualmente e possa garantir que essa condição não mudará para nulo depois) e usar um tipo comum.

Ainda existe o indicador de tipo `?` que faz o tipo sempre aceitar nulo e aí você tem que verificar o estado sempre antes de usar. O `!` não. Ele permite você entender que ele não é nulo no seu código Kotlin, mas ainda interoperar em Java. Antes de acessar em Kotlin precisa garantir que ele é válido, mas não depois. O `?` permite você anular o valor, o `!` não permite fazê-lo.

Existem casos que o Java pode dar pistas para inferir melhor a situação possível e já garantir que não é nulo. Existem casos que o tipo é inferido como `!` (possivelmente anulável).

Não tenho experiência suficiente, mas acho que se o dado é mutável e compartilhado com Java, dá na mesma porque você não pode nunca confiar nele em ambientes concorrentes ou que você passe o controle da execução para o Java no meio do processamento. E em OOP é fácil fazer isso sem perceber.

Ele acaba fazendo parte do tipo de dado. De fato, em Kotlin é chamado de tipo de plataforma (em alusão ao Java como plataforma). Eu precisaria pesquisar mais para entender se o compilador insere verificação em *runtime* ou não para garantir que saída para o Java garantem alguma verificação. Faz sentido fazer assim, mas não posso garantir e superficialmente não achei nada, então só fazendo um teste extensivo.

[Documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types).

Existe o [operador `!!`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226862/101) que força um erro de `NullPoiterException` se o objeto for nulo neste caso (colocando como curiosidade).

Há algo semelhante no C# 8, mas ele dá garantia que não é nulo. Algumas pessoas gostam de chamá-lo de *dammit operator*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Duas interrogações lança uma Exception, no caso de apenas uma interrogação, o que acontece se uma variável receber um valor nulo em tempo de execução, não sendo possível prever em tempo de compilação?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam lança uma exceção, o corre igual ao Java. Note que o `!!` é um operador, veja a outra pergunta lá pra entender, escrevi sobre ele mais pra introduzir a outra pergunta. Ainda há dúvida ou ficou claro?

Comment: Então nenhuma exclamação é erro de compilação, uma exclamação permite nulo e pode gerar uma exceção durante a execução, duas exclamações permite nulo mas gera uma exceção em execução equando isso ocorre, entendi certo?

Comment: Se tentar colocar um nulo em um tipo  dá erro de compilação. Com uma exclamação no tipo permite o nulo e pode gerar a exceção, duas exclamações não é que permite exceção, gera a exceção se for nulo, porque este é um operador. Existe ainda o `?` que define que o tipo pode ser anulável. Veja https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types. Eu vou complementar a resposta pra ficar mais completo e claro que esta anotação da exclamação ter a ver com iteroperabilidade.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam veja se melhorou. Melhorou o meu entendimento.

Comment: Com a sua edição e a outra resposta acho que entendi, valeu

Answer (score 3):

Significa que você está lidando com um [`platform type`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types): um tipo vindo do Java que pode ou não ser nulo.

O compilador do Kotlin sempre tenta buscar por [anotações de nulabilidade](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) e inferir se um tipo pode ser nulo ou não.

Caso as anotações estejam presentes, o tipo será representável como `nullable` (`CharSequence?`) ou não (`CharSequence`).

Caso as anotações não estejam presentes, ele será considerado um `platform type` (`CharSequence!`). Na prática isso significa que as checagens de nulo serão menos restritas. Quando métodos são chamados nestes tipos, não são gerados erros em tempo de compilação, mas podem acontecer erros em tempo de execução devido à checagem de nulos que o Kotlin gera para não propagar nulos.

Considere a seguinte atribuição, interoperando com o Java:

```
// Chamando código Java sem anotação de nulabilidade
val resultWithPlatFormType = myJavaObject.myJavaMethod()
```

A seguinte chamada pode gerar um erro em tempo de execução:

```
// Lançará uma exceção caso resultWithPlatFormType seja nulo
resultWithPlatFormType.trim()
```

Note que os `platform types` não são "anotáveis", ou seja, a linguagem não tem uma maneira formal de representá-los de forma explícita. 
Quando um destes tipos é atribuído a uma variável Kotlin, podemos usar a inferência de tipos ou escolher de forma explícita como queremos tratar o valor:

```
val inferred = myJavaObject.myJavaMethod() // Será inferido como platform type
val notNull: String = myJavaObject.myJavaMethod()  // Funciona, mas pode falhar em tempo de execução
val nullable: String? = myJavaObject.myJavaMethod() // Sempre funciona
```