# É uma prática ruim fazer esta comparação?

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, comparação

Para comparar dois valores com um único, posso fazer como no exemplo:

```
if(foo == "abc" || foo == "54") { ... }
```

Porém conforme preciso adicionar mais condições, isso começa a ficar complicado:

```
if(foo == "abc" || foo == "54" || foo == "23A" || foo == "3xe" || foo == "123") { ... }
```

Para contornar isso, eu coloco os valores de comparação em uma coleção e uso o `.Contains()`. Veja:

```
if(new String[] {"abc", "54", "23A", "3xe", "123"}.Contains(foo)) { ... }
```

Ele funciona assim como o operador OrElse (`||`).

É considerado uma prática ruim utilizar o `.Contains()` para esse tipo de comparação e por quê? Que outras alternativas melhores eu teria?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Como sempre repito, essa coisa de boa ou má prática depende de contexto. Neste caso sem saber todos os requisitos do que está fazendo não tem como responder. Ambos estão corretos e aceitáveis.

Se fizer o segundo para ficar mais curto, mais engraçadinho, em tese economizar digitação, então não deve fazer, não faz sentido. Principalmente em C# que privilegia o [tempo de compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216594/101).

O segundo passa ter um processamento em tempo de execução para resolver algo que poderia ter sido resolvido em tempo de compilação. Deixe o `Contains()` para casos onde não sabe qual é a lista de dados, ou ela pode ser mudada com frequência, ou se ela é muito muito grande, o que não parece nem perto de ser o caso.

Se C# tivesse alguma otimização que garantisse que o `Contains()` fosse [linearizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110886/101) e depois desenrolado, o que provavelmente geraria mais ou menos o mesmo código do primeiro, aí até poderia fazer. Tem linguagem que tem um operador para isto o que gera um código otimizado.

Mas se não tem preocupações com tempo de execução, pode fazer, apesar de eu não recomendar.

Mas tem que analisar o contexto, se faz sentido produzir uma lista, porque é isto que está manipulando, o que não parece ser o caso, faça uma lista. Se não é uma lista, o mais legível é o primeiro. Se for uma lista, não sei se deveria ser criada ali no `if`, provavelmente ela deveria estar em outro lugar. Faça o que demonstre melhor qual é a intenção, sempre.

Comment: acho que essa utilização do contains seria só pela digitação mesmo, muito boa resposta =]

Comment: Atrasado para a pergunta original, porém eu gostaria de complementar a resposta do @Maniero. Enquanto criar um array em tempo de execução e chamar um método `Contains` potencialmente linear não é uma boa idéia, existem estruturas como `HashSet` com tempo de *lookup* amortizado constante. Em especial, tive muito sucesso substituindo uma cadeia complicada de *ifs* com dezenas de condições por um `ImmutableHashSet` estático e uma chamada para `Contains`. Não só o código ficou mais limpo, a execução também ficou mais rápida (em um *trade-off* por um pouco de memória).

Comment: É verdade, se tiver muitos itens começa compensar fazer assim, principalmente se não vai dar `true` já nos primeiros itens na maior parte dos usos.

Comment: Uma vez eu li uma coisa que mudou minha maneira de pensar: Seu tempo como programador vale muito mais que algumas instruções de máquina. Não há nada de errado com seu código e ele não vai falhar (para strings).

Comment: @Edney por isso que deve fazer o certo porque em geral é o que dará menor trabalho e funcionará melhor, inclusive em boa parte dos casos o certo é o mais rápido. Existe uma diferença entre o certo, o errado e o de qualquer jeito, o mais perigoso é o de qualquer jeito porque parece certo mas não é.

Comment: Há muita discussão sobre "over optimization", se essa tarefa será usada 1 vez por mês, tanto faz... ela pode gastar 10^4 instruções a mais que tanto faz (mas ela tem que estar perfeitamente funcional). Agora se a tarefa será executada 10^3 vezes por micro segundo durante 10 anos, aí vale a pena otimizar o máximo que puder, mesmo que gaste 10^8 linhas de código a mais.

Comment: Quase todas discussões sobre otimização que tem por aí é falar receita de bolo, o certo é sempre fazer o que tem que fazer. Quando as pessoas começam não se preocupar com o que estão fazendo é quando começa dar problema. As pessoas acham que produzir rápido é mais importante que pensar no que está fazendo, e aí molda tudo o que elas fazem e chega um ponto que perder a referência do que é o certo a fazer, culpa das receitas de bolo. Adota-se elas porque é mais produtivo no curto prazo e pior no longo.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito ser preferível a utilização da segunda abordagem (utilizando o método `Contains`).

Há um grande ganho no que diz respeito a legibilidade e manutenibilidade do código.

Particularmente, prefiro declarar o array / list antes de usar na condição `if`. Acredito que desta forma a legibilidade do código fica ainda melhor. Desta forma:

```
var lista = new List<string> { "abc", "54", "23A", "3xe", "123" }

if (lista.Contains(foo)) { }
```

Uma outra alternativa (não muito boa, na minha opinião), seria a utilização de um `switch case`. Algo como:

```
  switch (foo)
  {
      case "abc":
      case "54":
      case "(etc...)":
          Console.WriteLine("Valor de foo:" + foo);
          break;
      default:
          Console.WriteLine("Foo não está especificado em nenhum case");
          break;

  }
```

Comment: Este `switch` não faz a mesma coisa.

Comment: @Maniero verdade, editado. Obrigado.

Comment: Mesmo com a edição, acho ele extramente pior e não mostra a intenção, pelo menos neste caso, embora realmente seja uma "alternativa".

Comment: Concordo com @Maniero, não faz sentido algum usar o switch em comparações onde tem condições OR ou AND

Answer (score 2):

Quanto a performance, é praticamente imperceptível aos olhos humanos, talvez seja em testes de benchmarking. Mas a não ser que você esteja escrevendo código para suporte a vida (área de medicina) ou outra área em que tempo de resposta é critico, não haverá problema.

Baseado nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907357/4343335), é possível escrever um método de extensão que *emula* o condicional **In** que normalmente usamos em SQL.

E.g.: `Select * from Produtos Where Id In (1,2,3,4,5);`

Eu particularmente acho mais bonito que a sintaxe do `Contains` que tem que passar a lista com as possibilidades primeiro, mas é questão de gosto.

**Ficaria assim o extension method:**

```
public static bool In<T>(this T obj, params T[] args)
{
    return args.Contains(obj);
}
```

**Utilização:**

```
if(foo.In("xyz", "abc", "123"))
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que não é uma pratica ruim, apenas uma forma de organizar e tornar o código um pouco mais fácil de entender. Se a quantidade de possibilidade for muito grande eu colocaria em um objeto separado.

```
var listaFoo = new List<string> { "abc", "54", "23A", "3xe", "123", "abc1", "154", "23A2", "34xe", "223" };
if (listaFoo.Contains(foo)) { }
```

Para casos com poucos elementos, pode ser declarado na propria condição:

```
if({"abc", "23A", "3xe", "123"}.Contains(foo)) 
{
```

Outra forma, porém um pouco maior e pior é :

```
switch(foo)
{
  case "abc":
  case "bcd":
  case "cdf":
    //do something
    break;
  case "xyz":
    //do something else
    break;
  default:
    //do a different thing
    break;
}
```

Agora se performance for muito importante pra você, esta é a forma com menos etapas de processamento:

```
if(foo == "abc" || foo == "54" || foo == "23A" || foo == "3xe" || foo == "123")
```

Comment: Este switch não faz a mesma coisa.

Comment: Agora faz, kkkkk. Faltava uma parte.

Comment: Não sei se entendi o `switch`, vez que para todos os _cases_ no meu exemplo eu faria a mesma coisa, não coisas diferentes, como posto em "do something", "do something else".

Comment: Eu apenas mencionei como possibilidade, mesmo ela sendo ruim.

Comment: Porque switch seria pior? Eu vejo switch interessante para certos casos (dependendo do que vai se executar dentro da condição), não tem essa de pior ou melhor sem contexto, ou seja sem saber o que será executado para cada "case".

Comment: Na minha opnião, fica pior no contexto do caso apresentando. Pois fica maior e um pouco menos  claro,  do que os itens anteriores. 
Em outros casos pode ficar melhor.