# Diferença do erro de compilação e execução

Tags: java, exceção, compilação, runtime

Um erro de compilação seria aquele que a IDE já avisa antes mesmo de compilar, como por exemplo a falta de um ponto e vírgula, correto? Mas e o erro de execução? Seria por exemplo, uma `Exception`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A resposta no geral já foi dada em [Qual a diferença entre "compile time" e "run time"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216594/101).

Não importa como ocorre, o que importa é que ele ocorra quando a aplicação está executando. Linguagens mais robustas tendem a evitar que erros fiquem para o tempo de execução. Mas tem vários casos que isto é impossível. Tem situações que você só sabe que o erro ocorreu no momento que ele está ocorrendo, não tem como antecipar que ele ocorrerá ou potencialmente ocorrerá, principalmente, mas não só, quando envolve dados externos que só são sabidos quando está executando.

Um exemplo é uma divisão por 0 quando o 0 é o valor de uma variável que só sabe seu valor na execução, seja por entrada de dados, seja porque para chegar nele passou por vários passos que seria impossível ou muito difícil concluir que ele é 0 em tempo de compilação.

Exemplos típicos são os indicados pelo sistema operacional, banco de dados, etc. São erros de funcionamento fora do controle da sua aplicação.

Existem erros que podem ser considerados de programação. Porque sempre que é possível que dê errado você deveria verificar antes e não deixar dar o erro. A divisão por 0 é um deles. Argumentos passados para funções são outros, índice de uma coleção de dados fora da faixa também.

Cada linguagem usa uma forma de indicar isso, a exceção é uma delas e é a mais básica usada pelo Java.

Mas o erro é detectado por outras formas antes de lançar a exceção, a exceção é só a superfície. Ela não ocorra sozinha, do nada. Há uma algoritmo que determinada que algo está errado e ela é lançada. Isto pode ser até algo que vem informado externamente e até mesmo do processador.

Sempre que uma exceção é lançado podemos dizer que houve um erro. Java tem a cultura de tratar até dados inválidos como erro, o que para muitos é um conceito errado, está usando exceção para algo não excepcional.

Qualquer erro que pode ser detectado em tempo de compilação deveria ser. Os erros de léxica, sintaxe e semântica do código podem ser detectado neste momento.

Tecnicamente não há como informar erro antes de compilar. O compilador é que detecta os erros. É possível um IDE invocar um compilador para fazer isso antes de gerar um executável.

[image: Erro de runtime depois de compilar]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Isso mesmo.

Erro de compilação: quando um caractere inválido ou sintáxe errada é encontrada no código.

Erro de execução: Após o código estar compilado, ao executar o projeto, encontra-se alguma exception de sql, casting, algum erro de cálculo, etc. Ou seja, o erro de execução seria um erro lógico e não um erro de "gramática" digamos.

Answer (score 1):

Erro de compilação é o erro que não deixa você gerar o executável ou a biblioteca, para que você a rode/corra.

Erro de execução é aquele que, como diz o nome, acontece só quando o executável ou biblioteca é rodada/corrida.

Um exemplo de erro de execução é quando o banco de dados está offline no momento da execução e você tenta acessá-lo/acedê-lo, ou quando o código tem erros semânticos, como o programa a seguir. Ele compila normalmente, mas você só vai descobrir o problema quando executá-lo:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Chamada ao método.
        String notGonnaHappen = throwStackOverflowError();
    }

    public static String throwStackOverflowError() {
        // Recursão infinita que o compilador não tem capacidade de verificar.
        return throwStackOverflowError();
    }
}
```