# Despacho múltiplo na linguagem Julia

Tags: característica-linguagem, julia

Estou estudando sobre a linguagem Julia e li que o despacho múltiplo permite que as funções sejam despachadas dinamicamente, mas ainda não ficou claro para mim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL; DR

É só uma [sobrecarga](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137185/101) de funções resolvida em tempo de execução. Se você sabe os tipos dos objetos em tempo de compilação não precisa deste mecanismo (desde que a linguagem permita resolver na compilação).

## Detalhando

Primeiro ponto a definir é que esse tipo de mecanismo só funciona em linguagem que possuem alguma forma dinâmica de execução, portanto a decisão sobre a chamada de uma função se dá só nom momento de ser chamada e não no momento da compilação como costuma acontecer em linguagens que tendem resolver tudo mais estaticamente.

As linguagens mais estáticas costumam fazer o despacho se baseando em uma informação que está disponível na compilação, por isso temos [polimorfismo *ad hoc* (ou sobrecarga) ou paramétrico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101).

Mesmo as linguagens mais estáticas costumam ter algum mecanismo de resolução de despacho de função dinamicamente, o que é conhecido como polimorfismo clássico ou de subtipo. Dependendo do objeto tratado é decidido qual método chamar. Ele usa apenas um critério para tomar a decisão, é o tipo de um argumento (costuma ser o primeiro que pode até ser oculto no código). É um mecanismo relativamente simples e o custo de [*runtime*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216594/101) dele é muito baixo.

O despacho múltiplo usa vários critérios para decidir o que chamar. Ele pode analisar os tipos de vários argumentos, os valores passados ou até outras informações que ajudem na decisão. Ele se assemelha muito com a sobrecarga de funções, mas difere porque a decisão depende do momento da execução, e dá mais flexibilidade.

Ele é uma forma de polimorfismo mais sofisticada.

Algumas linguagens que não possuem este tipo de mecanismo acabam resolvendo no código o que fazer, com `if`s ou alguma forma de `switch` incluindo [*pattern matching*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445451/101). O *multiple dispatch* faz isso por conta própria sem precisar desse tipo de código.

Uma solução para resolver em parte essa questão é implementar o [*Visitor pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Alguns casos com geração de código para facilitar.

Existem outras que acabam fazendo mais ou menos o mesmo que um compilador faria internamente no código de linguagens que suportam nativamente esse padrão, tal como acontece em Julia.

Algumas linguagens criam uma forma de você escrever as várias funções com as combinações possíveis de características diferentes dos argumentos.

As linguagens que não fazem isso e você não usa um gerador de código acaba gerando muito *boiler plate*, e as que fazem são boas facilitadoras para isso, ainda que gere um custo extra de processamento.

Em Julia você pode ter isto:

```
function collide(me::Circle, other::Rectangle)
function collide(me::Polygon, other::Circle)
function collide(me::Polygon, other::Rectangle)
```

E aí chama assim:

```
collide(objeto, outro)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Pattern.exs).

O que será chamado depende do tipo dessas duas variáveis no momento da execução, não se sabe de antemão e a decisão será tomada pelo *runtime* sem você ter que escrever código algum para tomar essa decisão.

Então se `objeto` for do tipo `Circle` e `outro` for do tipo `Rectangle` será a primeira função a ser chamada. Mas se `outro` for `Circle` e não importa qual `Polygon` seja o `objeto, a segunda função será chamada, e finalmente se o` outro`for um`Rectangle`e`objeto for qualquer `Polygon`, exceto um `Circle` que já tem um *match* melhor, então a terceira função será chamada. Note que dará erro se ambos forem um `Polygon` que o `outro` não seja `Circle` ou `Rectangle`.

Existe algo chamado *double dispatch* que é uma especialização do *multiple dispatch* para duas características que é diferente do *single dispatch* que tem apenas uma e é usada mais amplamente. É o que foi usado acima.

Também são chamados de multi-métodos.

[Documentação](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch).