# O que é uma virtual table?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, python, c++

Vi que algumas linguagens usam essa tal de *vtable* na sua implementação. O que é e para que serve?

Todas as linguagens são iguais no uso dela?

Em que parte da memória ela fica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *vtable*, como costuma ser chamada, é uma tabela dos [métodos virtuais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158579/101) a serem invocados quando um objeto está em uso. Portanto é algo de orientação a objeto, mais especificamente de [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101).

Também chamada de tabela de funções/métodos virtuais, tabela de despacho ou tabela de chamada virtual

O v de virtual é sobre os métodos virtuais que essas linguagens têm. Então *vtable* é uma tabela de métodos virtuais, ou seja, é uma lista (pode ser algo muito próximo ou ser um *array* de referências (ponteiros) para o código das funções que servem como métodos).

Quando há polimorfismo é necessário ter uma forma de decidir qual código será executado de acordo com o tipo do objeto que está sendo manipulado. Existem algumas formas de realizar polimorfismo, uma delas é dinâmico, é usando [*late biding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/577332/101) e precisa de um mecanismo para controlar isso.

Embora possa fazer de formas diferentes na prática a *virtual table* costuma ser a mais adequada.

O termo *vtable* é muito usado no contexto de C++, mas mecanismos parecidos existem em outras linguagens. Porém "nunca" é igual.

C++ só tem essa estrutura de dados chamada *vtable* para tipos que possuem métodos virtuais, ou seja, que fazem polimorfismo. A filosofia da linguagem é pagar só pelo que usa.

C# tem essa estrutura sempre e está atrelada ao tipo, tendo métodos virtuais ou não, a única otimização é não usá-la quando não é necessário.

Java não é diferente, só que usa a *vtable* do tipo sempre, mesmo sem necessidade, a não ser que o JITter faça alguma otimização quando ele percebe ser desnecessário, mas não é algo determinado pela linguagem.

Linguagens com características mais dinâmicas têm uma forma de *vtable*, usam sempre, e mais, costumam ter até uma *vtable* por objeto e não apenas uma por tipo.

Isso dá grande flexibilidade para os objetos, mas cobra o preço da performance e consumo de memória.

O uso em linguagens dinâmicas, talvez especialmente JavaScript, ajude entender a *vtable*, porque sabemos que um objeto nesta e outras linguagens de mesma filosofia na verdade possuem protótipos, que nada mais são que [*arrays* associativos com os membros do objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/101). Sendo que pode ter alguns membros que guardam valores, que são os campos, e outros membros que são os métodos, que não deixa de ser um valor guardado com o ponteiro para qual função deve executar. Cada objeto pode mudar completamente. Dá até pra trocar a função de uma hora para outra. Já respondido com mais detalhes em outras respostas.

Em linguagens mais estáticas não tem essa flexibilidade, só é necessário, potencialmente, mudar qual é o método a ser chamado se o tipo for mais específico, mas não a cada objeto. Então a estrutura de dados não fica junto do objeto, fica junto ao tipo, sendo que C++ não tem maiores informações sobre o tipo, tipicamente, e a *vtable* fica sozinha.

Estritamente falando as linguagens mais dinâmicas não têm exatamente uma *vtable*, tem algo mais poderoso, e ineficiente. Mas tem algo muito parecido. A *vtable* seria auxiliar e não parte do objeto. O mecanismo de indireção do polimorfismo é idêntico, mas feito diretamente no objeto.

Então todo objeto que tem uma forma de polimorfismo, usado efetivamente ou não, precisa estar ligado a uma estrutura de dados com a lista de métodos virtuais que ele tem para ser chamado. Pode ser a própria estrutura do objeto, ou pode ser algo separado em algum ponto da memória dedicado a isto, provavelmente em memória estática que o compilador disponibiliza. Obviamente que se estiver atrelado ao objeto então fica na memória dinâmica (muito eventualmente na automática).

A referência para a *vtable* costuma ficar em um preâmbulo do objeto, conforme já relatado em várias respostas aqui ([exemplo em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161846/101)).

Bem grosso modo, nas linguagens estáticas, pode entender que ela é algo assim:

```
List<Function> vtable_Animal = { Animal_Come(), Animal_Anda() };
List<Function> vtable_Gato = { Gato_Come(), Gato_Anda() };
```

Obviamente que `Gato` é o tipo que herda de `Animal`.

Então cada objeto precisa ter uma referência para `vtable_Animal` se ele for do tipo `Animal`, e para `vtable_Gato` se for do tipo `Gato`.

Aí, quando for chamar o método `Come()` de um objeto, ele vai descobrir qual método deve chamar consultado a tabela em vez de chamar a função de forma direta. Isso é chamado [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). Se o objeto foi declarado com o tipo `Animal` então chamará o `Animal_Come()`, mas se o tipo do objeto for `Gato` chamará `Gato_Come()`. Então a chamada do método é para um ponteiro para a *vtable* que tem um ponteiro para o método. A chamada já considera o elemento da lista, no exemplo `Come()` é o primeiro elemento.

Claro que tudo isso depende de implementação, a não ser que alguma linguagem especifique que só pode ser de um jeito por alguma razão. Cada detalhe tem que ser procurado onde está usando. De qualquer forma por ser um detalhe de implementação não costuma ser extensivamente documentado. Você não precisa saber para usar.

Então essa forma seria até mais simplificada em C++ e só teria a estrutura se realmente esses dois métodos demonstrados são virtuais (a tabela existiria se existisse um só método virtual).

Em C# a tabela seria muito maior, e complexa, com todos os métodos. Mas a tabela só seria consultada quando o método for declarado como `virtual`. Em Java ela seria sempre consultada, a não ser que o JITter otimize.

A consulta seria justamente pegar o ponteiro da tabela e aí consultar o ponteiro do método contido nela para chamar a execução adequada, diferente do método não virtual que já tem o ponteiro que deve ser usado para chamar a execução, não tem que selecionar qual método é o adequado.

Para dar uma ideia mais próxima de como é de fato em C++ (mas ainda não é a forma real):

```
struct Foo { virtual ~Foo(); virtual int a() { return 1; } };
struct Bar: public Foo { int a() { return 2; } };
void f(Foo& arg) {
  Foo x; x.a(); // non-virtual: always calls Foo::a()
  Bar y; y.a(); // non-virtual: always calls Bar::a()
  arg.a();      // virtual: must dispatch via vtable
  Foo z = arg;  // copy constructor Foo::Foo(const Foo&) will convert to Foo
  z.a();        // non-virtual Foo::a, since z is a Foo, even if arg was not
}
```

Se transforma em (note o uso de `struct` para formar a estrutura com  lista de métodos):

```
typedef struct Foo_t Foo;   // forward declaration
struct slotsFoo {           // list all virtual functions of Foo
  const void *parentVtable; // (single) inheritance
  void (*destructor)(Foo*); // virtual destructor Foo::~Foo
  int (*a)(Foo*);           // virtual function Foo::a
};
struct Foo_t {                      // class Foo
  const struct slotsFoo* vtable;    // each instance points to vtable
};
void destructFoo(Foo* self) { }     // Foo::~Foo
int aFoo(Foo* self) { return 1; }   // Foo::a()
const struct slotsFoo vtableFoo = { // only one constant table
  0,                                // no parent class
  destructFoo,
  aFoo
};
void constructFoo(Foo* self) {      // Foo::Foo()
  self->vtable = &vtableFoo;        // object points to class vtable
}
void copyConstructFoo(Foo* self,
                      Foo* other) { // Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
  self->vtable = &vtableFoo;        // don't copy from other!
}

typedef struct Bar_t {              // class Bar
  Foo base;                         // inherit all members of Foo
} Bar;
void destructBar(Bar* self) { }     // Bar::~Bar
int aBar(Bar* self) { return 2; }   // Bar::a()
const struct slotsFoo vtableBar = { // one more constant table
  &vtableFoo,                       // can dynamic_cast to Foo
  (void(*)(Foo*)) destructBar,      // must cast type to avoid errors
  (int(*)(Foo*)) aBar
};
void constructBar(Bar* self) {      // Bar::Bar()
  self->base.vtable = &vtableBar;   // point to Bar vtable
}
```

Usando:

```
void f(Foo* arg) {                  // same functionality as above
  Foo x; constructFoo(&x); aFoo(&x);
  Bar y; constructBar(&y); aBar(&y);
  arg->vtable->a(arg);              // virtual function call
  Foo z; copyConstructFoo(&z, arg);
  aFoo(&z);
  destructFoo(&z);
  destructBar(&y);
  destructFoo(&x);
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29546612/221800).

Detalhe que você pode usar uma *vtable* em praticamente [qualquer linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101), talvez todas de alguma forma, [até mesmo em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80228/101). Sempre que o polimorfismo dinâmico for útil, se a linguagem não fornece o recurso, o programador cria e usa manualmente sem ajuda do compilador.

Eventualmente pode usar indireção de campos também, especialmente em [múltipla herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/101).

Para múltipla herança é necessária uma técnica um pouco mais sofisticada para lidar com dois ou mais ramos de herança, eventualmente até acessando mais de uma *vtable*.

Esta técnica não é suficiente em linguagens que precisam fazer [despachos múltiplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/448123/101).

Geralmente isto faz parte da [ABI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187944/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/Vtable.cpp).