# Estou tendo problema ao tentar listar dados de uma tabela mysql

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, jdbc, tabela-banco-de-dados

**Classe Fabrica**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class Fabrica {
    
    public  Connection getConexao() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste", "root", "123");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
    
}
```

**Classe AlunoDAO**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class AlunoDAO {
    
private Connection conn;
    
    public void insert(String nome, int matricula) {
        String sql = "insert into aluno values (?,?)";
        conn = new Fabrica().getConexao();
        
        try {
           
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, nome);
            ps.setInt(2, matricula);          
            ps.execute();
            ps.close();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(AlunoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void select() {
        String sql = "select * from aluno";
        
        try {
            
            
            PreparedStatement ps = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql); //linha 41
            
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
            while(result.next()) {
                System.out.println(result.getString("nome"));
                System.out.println(result.getInt("matricula"));
            }              
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Classe MAIN**

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        AlunoDAO dao = new AlunoDAO();
        
    
        dao.select(); //linha 10
    }
}
```

> **ERRO:**
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at AlunoDAO.select(AlunoDAO.java:41)
>
> at Principal.main(Principal.java:10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O mais correto seria inicializar `conn` no constutor do seu DAO. Esse código não funciona porque ela (`conn`) é nula. Só é instanciada no método `insert()` mas não no `select()`.

Uma vez com a conexão já criada você pode remover os outros pontos onde fez manualmente. Sempre prefira capturar a exception mais especifica e não mais genérica. Sugiro a leitura de algumas perguntas da [tag exception](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

veja o trecho do insert():

```
public void insert(String nome, int matricula) {
    String sql = "insert into aluno values (?,?)";
    conn = new Fabrica().getConexao(); //<--Aqui, pega a conexão o que não acontece no select
```

**Solução:**

```
public class AlunoDAO {
  private Connection conn;
  public void AlunoDAO(Connection conn){
    conn = conn;
  }
```

A chamda deve ficar:

```
AlunoDAO dao = new AlunoDAO(new Fabrica().getConexao());
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Como funciona o try-with-resources?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/91)

[Há algum inconveniente em sempre capturar Exception e não algo mais específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/91)

[Melhor maneira de lidar com Exceptions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13303/91)

[Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/91)

[O que é injeção de dependência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20770/91)

[Quais as diferenças entre Injeção de Dependência e Inversão de Controle?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/91)

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do @rray, se você não quiser ter que passar a conexão toda vez que instanciar um **AlunoDAO** pode fazer assim:

**Fabrica**:

```
public class Fabrica {

    public static Connection getConexao() {
        static Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste", "root", "123");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

**AlunoDAO** (Construtor) Pode então usar o `conn` em todos os métodos de AlunoDAO.:

```
public class AlunoDAO {
  private Connection conn;
  public void AlunoDAO(){
    conn = Fabrica.getConexao();
  }
```

**Chamada**:

```
AlunoDAO dao = new AlunoDAO();
```

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui, ao botar o conn = Fabrica.getConexao(); no select().