# Erro: java.lang.NullPointerException em projeto utilizando JDBC

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jdbc

Poderiam me ajudar com o erro abaixo, trata-se de um, estou com erro nas linhas 14 da classe TestaLista e erro na linha 32 da classe `ContatoDao`.

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDao.getLista(ContatoDao.java:28)
>     at br.com.caelum.jdbc.teste.TestaLista.main(TestaLista.java:14)
> ```

Classe `TestaLista`:

```java
public class TestaLista {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RuntimeException{

        ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao();
        List<Contato> contatos = dao.getLista(); // <-- Aponta erro nessa parte

        for(Contato contato : contatos) {
            System.out.println("Nome: " + contato.getNome());
            System.out.println("Email: " + contato.getEmail());
            System.out.println("Endereço: " + contato.getEndereco());
            System.out.println("Data de Nascimento: " + 
                            contato.getDataNascimento().getTime() + "\n") ;
        }
    }
}
```

Classe `ContatoDao`, com erro no `PreparedStatement`:

```java
public class ContatoDao {
    private Connection connection;

    public void adiciona(Contato contato) {
        String sql = "insert into contatos" + 
                "(nome, email, endereco, dataNascimento)" + 
                "values(?,?,?,?)";  
    }

    public List<Contato> getLista(){
        try {
            List<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<Contato>();
            PreparedStatement stmt = this.connection
                    .prepareStatement("select * from contatos"); // <-- Aponta erro nessa parte...
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {

                //Objeto contato
                Contato contato = new Contato();
                contato.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
                contato.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                contato.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                contato.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));

                //montando a data com Calendar
                Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
                data.setTime(rs.getDate("dataNascimento"));
                contato.setDataNascimento(data);

                contatos.add(contato);
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            return contatos;
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Seguem as classes de conexão:

```java
public class ConnectionFactory {
    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/fj21?useSSL=false", "root", "");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }   
}
```

Classe `ConnectionTeste`:

```java
public class ConnectionTeste {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Connection connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
        System.out.println("Conexão aberta!");
        connection.close();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Sua conexao pode estar nula, certifique-sempre de iniciar a conexao antes de criar um Statement.

Comment: Sem olhar direito e mesmo sem ter informações suficientes acho que posso afirmar que o problema é falta de inicialização de `connection`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Estou tendo problema ao tentar listar dados de uma tabela mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/238820/28595)

Comment: @Articuno o link vc passou ajudou em algumas correções mas continuo com o mesmo problema :/

Comment: Se você não iniciar a conexão, o problema jamais será resolvido mesmo.

Comment: Veja também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos alterar um detalhe na sua `ConnectionFactory`:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/fj21?useSSL=false", "root", "");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }   
}
```

O detalhe é aquele modificador `static` a mais.

Agora, a sua classse `ConnectionTeste` sofre uma alteração:

```
public class ConnectionTeste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection()) {
            System.out.println("Conexão aberta!");
        }
    }
}
```

Com isso, vamos refazer o seu DAO:

```
public class ContatoDao {

    private static final String INSERT_SQL = ""
            + "INSERT INTO Contatos"
            + "(nome, email, endereco, dataNascimento)"
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private static final String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM Contatos";

    public void adiciona(Contato contato) {
        // String sql = INSERT_SQL;  
    }

    public List<Contato> getLista() {
        try (
            Connection c = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(SELECT_SQL);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ) {
            List<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {

                //Objeto contato
                Contato contato = new Contato();
                contato.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
                contato.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                contato.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                contato.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));

                //montando a data com Calendar
                Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
                data.setTime(rs.getDate("dataNascimento"));
                contato.setDataNascimento(data);

                contatos.add(contato);
            }
            return contatos;
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Sua classe `TestaLista` permanece praticamente igual:

```
public class TestaLista {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao();
        List<Contato> contatos = dao.getLista();

        for (Contato contato : contatos) {
            System.out.println("Nome: " + contato.getNome());
            System.out.println("Email: " + contato.getEmail());
            System.out.println("Endereço: " + contato.getEndereco());
            System.out.println("Data de Nascimento: " + 
                    contato.getDataNascimento().getTime() + "\n") ;
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que usei o [***try-with-resources***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) em todos os casos.

Recomendo também usar a classe [**`LocalDate`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132) ao invés de `Calendar` para representar datas.

Comment: Victor Stafusa, consegui mestre! muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Então erro do meu código era na declaração do meu código SQL?

Comment: @ThiagoPernomian Não. O erro era o campo `connection` no seu `ContatoDao` que estava `null`.