# Instanciando o contexto da base de dados no controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Olá, tenho uma dúvida relacionado ao modo de instanciamento do DbContext no controlador. Qual a diferença entre os dois métodos abaixo de instanciamento ?

1.

```
    private ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public ApplicationDbContext db
    {
        get { return _db ?? new ApplicationDbContext(); }
        set { _db = value; }
    }
```

2.

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

Pois atualmente eu utilizo a segunda, porem em vários modelos de ASP.NET MVC 5 vejo que vem como padrão a primeira opção...

Comment: Na verdade se você instância assim já é errado as duas formas ... !!! no sentido funcional os dois funcionam do mesmo jeito e traz o que precisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, a única diferença que vejo é que na primeira opção caso o valor de _db estiver nulo ele ira gerar uma nova instância, adiciona uma certa segurança a sua implementação, mas, como foi já foi comentado, a não ser que este seja apenas um projeto de testes, vejo dois problemas nisso:

1 - Ao utilizar o "new" é criado uma dependencia entre o seu controller e a classe "ApplicationDbContext", o ideal seria utilizar [Injeção de dependencia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20770/o-que-%C3%A9-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia) para reduzir o acoplamento entre as camadas de sua aplicação.

2 - Ao realizar consultas no banco diretamente do controller, você está impedindo que ela possa ser reutilizada em outras partes do projeto, pois só estará acessivel dentro desse controller

Mas da pra citar vários outros problemas nessa abordagem....

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela resposta e pela citação da injeção de dependência. Mas pelo que entendi nesse assunto, eu teria que passar o contexto(ApplicationDbContext) via construtor (obedecendo a Injeção de Dependência) em todas as actions que fossem utilizar a classe "ApplicationDbContext" e em qual momento eu instancio a mesma? Porque ao meu ver, na situação de Controller  e Actions, não acho que será viável utilizar essa arquitetura...

Comment: Bem, a injeção de dependencia tem suas vantagens ao reduzir o acoplamente e facilar a manutenção do código, já que as modificações que vc realizar não irão impactar em outras áreas do seu projeto, mas ela é de certa forma mais trabalhosa, exige outras configurações, então embora seja uma boa prática, dependendo do tamanho e complexidade do seu projeto, não irá valer a pena.

"qual momento eu instancio a mesma?"

Na verdade vc não instancia, a instancia é "injetada" pra você em tempo de execução via construtor, ou seja existe um new por debaixo dos panos.

Comment: Entendi, e pelo que vi, tem que se utilizar de algumas ferramentas pra instanciar a classe no construtor quando se inicializa a aplicação na Startup.cs, bom vou pesquisar mais afundo aqui, mas tenho a intenção de tornar essa aplicação para grande escala