# Método Genérico de uma Classe Genérica C# para classes semelhantes

Tags: c#, asp.net, crud

Tenho algumas classes que vão utilizar um método gravar.
Criei uma classe CRUD (Genérica) onde teria um método gravar, porém preciso que esse método receba como parâmetro as classes.

Existe algum jeito de criar um método genérico pelo que li, mas não consegui passar um tipo de parâmetro que atenda a todas as classes.

Por exemplo, esse mesmo método vai gravar a empresa, contato, cliente no banco, sendo o a função add do EF.

Abaixo método que criei, mas ele nesse caso só atende para a classe Empresa.

```
public void Gravar<T>(Empresa obj)
    {
        context.Empresa.Add(obj);
    }
```

Como fazer para que no lugar de Empresa, sirva para a classe Contato, Cliente, Usuário, etc.? Do jeito que está eu teria que criar um gravar() para cada classe.

Comment: Seria ```public void Gravar<T>(T obj) { context.Set<T>.Add(obj) }``` ? Não sei se estou correto, então não coloquei como resposta

Comment: Se você quer criar um repositório genérico (tipo `T`), uma exemplo bem legal que vai ajudar está nesse *git*: https://github.com/lukemcgregor/StaticVoid.Repository/blob/master/StaticVoid.Repository.EntityFramework/DbContextRepositoryDataSource.cs

Comment: Valeu galera! Deu certo! Ainda um pouco perdido com OO, mas com tempo vou pegando melhor isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa passar a entidade genérica no parâmetro, ficaria assim

```
public void Gravar<T>(T obj)
{
    context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
}
```

Para chamar isso você precisa apenas passar o objeto como parâmetro, ele irá entender o tipo dele

```
Empresa empresa = new Empresa
{
    Nome = "Empresa"
};

Gravar(empresa);
```

Comment: Tentei dessa forma, porém ocorre o erro:
DbContext.Set<TEntity>() is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Você está fazendo uma classe genérica com esses métodos? se sim, tem como adicionar ela na pergunta. esse erro, geralmente, é "falha" ao instanciar o contexto

Comment: Sim, criei uma classe chamada CRUD para chamar os métodos em outras classes (Empresa, Contato, Usuário).

Comment: Seria possível adicionar essa classe toda na pergunta?

Comment: Cara deu certo! Agora só preciso entender como nao ter que ficar instanciando a classe CRUD pra poder usar o método pra cada classe. Tipo nao ter q instanciar Crud pra Empresa, pra Contato, Usuario.. Dai acho que envolve mais conhecimento em OO, que nesse caso acho que seria usar abstracao ou polimorfismo.

Comment: @JoãoBorba Pesquise um pouco sobre [Injeção de dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20770/o-que-%C3%A9-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia), acho que irá te ajudar nesse caso, tenho um modelo de projeto no meu github, se quiser pode pega-lo - [link](https://github.com/leobarbetta/ProjetoBase)

Answer (score 0):

Como fiz:
Na minha classe CRUD (Genérica) deixei assim:

```
public class Crud
        {
        public void Gravar(T obj)
        {
            context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private readonly ModelConexao context;

        public Crud(ModelConexao _context)
        {
            context = _context;
        }
```

E na minha classe do formulário chamei o método assim:

```
protected void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ModelConexao db = new ModelConexao())
            {
                T emp = new T()
                {                   
                    dominio = txtEmpresa.Text.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault(),
                    banco = "empresa_" + txtEmpresa.Text.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault(),
                    nome = txtEmpresa.Text.ToString()
                };

                Crud empresa = new Crud(db);
                empresa.Gravar(emp);
```

Só que tive que instanciar ali a classe Crud, e acho que o correto seria alguma forma de não ter que ficar instanciando pra cada entidade, pois nesse mesmo código eu tenho que dar um Gravar para a entidade Contato.

Mas cara obrigado pela ajuda! Aos poucos vou aprendendo...