# Qual a vantagem da injeção de dependência em relação a uma instância de um objeto?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, injeção-de-dependência

Tenho lido e relido [O que é injeção de dependência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20770/o-que-%C3%A9-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia) mas no final das contas não consegui perceber uma vantagem da injeção de dependência em relação a uma instância de objeto.

- Qual a vantagem da injeção de dependência em relação a uma instância de um objeto?

Disso:

```
Service service = new Service();
```

Para:

```
IService _service;

public Construtor(IService service)
    _service = service;
}
```

Fui pesquisar e acabei encontrando [Difference between creating new object and dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386889/difference-between-creating-new-object-and-dependency-injection), mas nem quem respondeu a pergunta souber dizer complemente essa diferença.

Comment: Mas da segunda forma você terá que passar a instância de `Repository` como parâmetro. Não entendi porque achou que essas formas são exclusivas. Elas não se complementam?

Comment: Eu não conseguir entender bem a pergunta pq ela fala de 2 coisas muito diferentes, mas veja se isso ajuda: Sem injeção de dependencia: Dentro da classe "Classe B" tem algo instanciando "Classe A". Com injeção de dependência: Você tem ClasseB, mas passa a Classe A como parâmetro na criação ou em algum método da B. A vantagem? Amanhã se você quiser que a Classe B funcione com a Classe C, sem injeção você vai ter que mexer no código da Classe B. Com a injeção, basta passar a Classe C no lugar da Classe A, pq a Classe B independe da Classe A;

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Em essência a vantagem é a flexibilidade.

Entenda que DI (Dependency Injection) é um nome pomposo para algo muito simples. Eu já falei sobre isso em um par de pergunta e [resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22422/101). É só parametrizar um objeto que precisa em determinado lugar, seja um algoritmo ou estrutura.

Quando você aceita um parâmetro com o objeto que deve ser usado no método, e que pode opcionalmente ser armazenado em uma instância de outro objeto, é possível trabalhar com objetos de tipos diversos que aceitem o mesmo contrato. Então a vantagem é quase a mesma de aceitar parâmetro em qualquer outra coisa. Exemplo:

```js
metodo() => for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) print(i);
```

Agora com parâmetro, que não deixa de ser uma dependência que você está injetando (você dependia de um valor que está fixo aí no código, agora depende do parâmetro):

```js
metodo(int x) => for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) print(i);
```

Agora ficou mais flexível. Simples, né? Tão óbvio que ninguém pensa sobre isso.
Agora troque o `int` por um objeto mais complexo e tem o que escreveu na pergunta.

Claro que tem algo a mais no mecanismo de DI que se conhece, você não faz com o mesmo tipo de objeto, e sim com o mesmo tipo base, assim você pode ser mais flexível usando o mecanismo de polimorfismo.

Veja [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).

Se você sabe que usará sempre o mesmo tipo então não faz muito sentido usar esse mecanismo. Geralmente o uso de DI viola o [YAGNI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/101) (*You Ain't Gonna Need It*). O caso do serviço pode ser necessário mesmo, porém o uso de serviços pode ser questionado, nem sempre precisa de fato. Pode ser só uma complicação criada para seguir a moda atual. Pode ser que precise do serviço, mas não precise parametrizá-lo, ou pelo menos não precisa sempre. Pode ter algo assim:

```java
class SeiLá {
    public Método() {
        Service service = new Service();
        ...
    }
    public Método(IService service) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Obrigar o programador a criar uma instância no local do consumo é o fim da picada. Ainda mais se for usado assim só para testes.

## Testes

Se é só por causa do teste faça assim:

```java
class SeiLá {
    public Método() {
        Service service = new Service();
        ...
    }
    [Debug] //ou use aqui outro mecanismo que nem mande este método para o executável
    public Método(IService service) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Quem gosta de fazer testes usa muito DI só por causa do teste. Eu não gosto disso e acho que a linguagem e as ferramentas que você usa deveriam cuidar disso. Você não deveria ter que mudar o *design* da sua aplicação para atender um requisito exclusivo do teste mas que não seja do domínio do problema que está solucionando. Tem quem discorde.

Quando vai testar algo complexo pode ficar lento, depender de algum mecanismo pesado, caro e que pode não estar disponível no momento do teste, ou ainda que você não tem controle sobre a resposta que ele dará. Para garantir que o teste seja adequado e leve, você substitui o mecanismo original, que poderia usar direto, por outro simples e controlado por você. Então, quando for testar, você chama passando um objeto de mesmo contrato, ou seja, derivado de uma classe ou interface igual, aí ele executa tudo o que precisa de forma diferente.

O que ninguém te conta é que entre o teste e o real pode ter tanta coisa diferente que o teste pode não ter a relevância que espera, ou para ter pode incorrer em custo incompatível com o projeto.

Esses dias vi uma palestra de uma pessoa falando de testes, depois conversando com a pessoa ela dizia que só testava uma parte crucial do sistema. Ora, na palestra deu a impressão que era tudo. Que sem teste não pode fazer nada. As pessoas fazem muito isso, falam uma coisa que sequer elas praticam, só porque é prazeroso falar do que está na moda e que as pessoas vão aplaudir, mas talvez a pessoa nem saiba porque usa aquilo, ainda assim ela se coloca como especialista.

No seu exemplo em vez de usar um serviço real você usa um que responde o que você quer para testar de forma simples, direta e controlada, e rodando levemente.

Como você mudaria isso durante o teste sem um parâmetro? Se a linguagem ajudar e permitir escrever esta seleção de acordo com alguma variável de compilação ou alguma ferramenta que manipula o código no momento da compilação ou até em algum momento seguinte faz isso com pouca ou zero intervenção no código em si. Essa é a forma correta, mas a maioria das ferramentas que tem por aí não fazem isso. É o que eu repito: as pessoas, até engenheiros de primeira linha, seguem muitas fórmulas prontas, não pensam em qual é o real problema e qual é a solução adequada para resolver isso. Aí elas colocam no domínio o que é mecanismo auxiliar.

Se o teste fosse rodado durante o uso em produção, claro que faria sentido, mas se é teste de *design* e fabricação, não faz sentido manter penduricalhos nele.

Hoje já questiono até a flexibilidade necessária. Para teste, questiono muito mais. Deveria resolver em tempo de compilação. A injeção de dependência é uma solução de tempo de execução, e na maioria das vezes você já sabe em tempo de compilação como resolver aquilo, pra que deixar esse fardo para depois?

Uma solução melhor é usar *generics* (não estou dizendo que para este caso é a melhor solução):

```cs
class SeiLa<T> where T : IService {
    public Método() {
        T service = new T();
        ...
    }
}
```

Flexibilizei sem precisar resolver em tempo de execução (depende de implementação), sem criar uma variável na instância. Mas note que isso é adequado para quando precisa mudar mesmo, se for só para testar acho até isto um exagero. Isto é DI com polimorfismo paramétrico.

Se for só para teste fica complicado postar algo aqui porque depende de ferramentas específicas, e que quase sempre não estão disponíveis, e em muitos casos você teria que desenvolver porque fica um monte de gente seguindo a caravana errada e deixar de fazer o certo. Uma forma tosca:

```java
class SeiLá {
    public Método() {
        #TService service = new #TService();
        ...
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/DependencyInjection.ptg).

Onde `TService` é uma variável de compilação e `#` é o que se usa para indicar isto.

#### Motivo para o tempo de execução

Eu costumo dizer que só existem dois motivos para resolver algo em tempo de execução:

- o dado só está disponível no momento da execução, depende de entrada de dados do usuário por teclado, mouse, microfone, ou outro dispositivo de entrada ou ainda que vem de rede, sistema de arquivos, banco de dados, serviços diversos, ou algo que o sistema operacional informa na hora, como a própria hora, por exemplo.
- por conveniência, então poderia resolver na compilação, mas o código ficará mais complexo, mais difícil de escrever e entender, de dar manutenção, maior no binário, mais lento, etc.

## Conclusão

Se é algo do sistema e não vem de fora, sempre tem como resolver na compilação. Aí decide o que fará o código ser mais simples, mais rápido, mais robusto, use DI quando atender isso (dica: as pessoas usam mesmo quando torna o código mais complicado, mais lento e menos robusto, mas em nome da robustez). Quase sempre é não usando DI. Mas é batalha perdida. Essa mentira foi contada tantas vezes que muitas pessoas acham que deve usar sempre.

DI é só um jeito específico de usar polimorfismo. A instância do objeto você terá de qualquer jeito, a questão é se determinará o tipo do objeto no código que está trabalhando agora ou deixará o consumidor dele determinar qual é.

[image: Cadeira de plástico no lugar do banco original do carro]

Comment: Poderia explicar a imagem no final para quem não enxergou o óbvio por favor? Sei que dizem que piada explicada não tem graça, mas as vezes não tem jeito, rsrsrs...
Parabéns pelo texto.

Comment: O normal é você ter o banco original, quando cria DI você deixa uma lugar vago pra alguém colocar o banco que quiser, e normalmente é isto que irá acontecer, a pessoa não vai colocar o banco certinho. Você criou algo que dá trabalho para o usuário e ele provavelmente fará errado. Faz o seu direito e dê pronto. Pelo menos dê um padrão e uma opção de parametrização.

Comment: Conversando mais com um amigo ontem, ele me explicou que uma grande vantagem de `DI` para uma instância é que por você depender de uma abstração onde há um contrato uma mudança significativa não alteraria todo o código em si. Obrigado Maneiro, excelente resposta.

Comment: Que é o que eu falei, e que quase sempre não precisa disto. E que as pessoas usam DI porque um dia pode precisar, mas quase sempre nunca precisa, aí enche de penduricalho pra nada. Quase todo mundo que usa DI não sabe o que está fazendo, segue a receita que lhes foi ensinada.

Answer (score 6):

Um exemplo de código usando instância de um objeto.

```java
public interface DebugInterface {
 
    void error(string message);

}

public class Debug implements DebugInterface {

    public void error(string message) {
        // código que faz uma coisa com a mensagem
    }
}

...

// Para você usar seria.
DebugInterface debug = new Debug();
```

Agora imagina que você usa essa classe em várias partes do seu código e você quer substituir essa implementação por outra. Você teria que substituir cada linha em cada classe que está importando o `Debug` e cada linha em que implementa o `Debug`. A quantidade de modificações varia de linguagem para linguagem, mas no geral, você teria que fazer várias modificações.

Usando a injeção por dependência, você não teria que substituir linha por linha caso queira substituir o antigo `Debug` por outra classe como:

```java
public class DebugModificado implements DebugInterface {

    public void error(string message) {
        // faz outra coisa com a mensagem
    }
}

...
// E substuir cada linha de
DebugInterface debug = new Debug();

// Para
DebugInterface debug = new DebugModificado();
```

Essa implementação seria feita em outra parte do código (varia de linguagem para linguagem), e seu código seria assim:

```java
DebugInterface debug = new DebugInterface();
```

Dessa forma, sempre que você quisesse trocar a implementação dessa interface, bastaria trocar apenas uma linha de código (que seria onde você define a injeção por dependência).

Answer (score 3):

A resposta sobre o que é injeção de dependência já foi respondida em alguns posts na rede.

Para tentar tornar a coisa mais fácil, digamos o seguinte:

Sempre que queremos criar um objeto é necessário o uso da palavra **new**, e neste caso, sempre que necessitas de um objeto do tipo pessoa você tem que usar `new Pessoa()`.

***É aqui que a injeção de dependência faz a diferença.***

Ela existe para que o código fique mais limpo e eficiente. Pense na injeção de dependência como variáveis globais que podem ser acessadas em todos os programas.

Por exemplo imagina que tem um serviço que é único no seu programa ou uma classe que é única como uma conexão a uma base de dados. Então tiras partido da injeção de dependência, onde em vez de criares uma conexão nova todas as vezes que necessitas de te ligar a base de dados, fazes uso da que criastes no início do programa.

Exemplo no Angular:

```js
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }
```

uso

```js
this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(res => this.users = res);
```

Desta forma estás a usar sempre o mesmo objeto e não precisas de criar novos objetos para fazer o mesmo.