# SOLID é tudo isso que dizem?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, solid, princípios-de-programação

Relacionada: [O que são os princípios SOLID?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178718/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-princ%C3%ADpios-solid)

Encomendei meu *"Princípios, Padrões e Práticas Ágeis em C#"* do Robert C. Martin e um dos motivos é o SOLID. Mas sou reticente quanto ao SOLID.

Eu nem conheço os princípios todos. Conheço o SOLI, falta o D. O caso é que vejo os princípios e penso "certo, e aí?". Alguns deles me parecem que não vêm com parâmetros dizendo onde devem ser aplicados, ou como. São mais reativos que prescritivos. São meio como padrões (recorrências) de projeto: você primeiro identifica uma situação em que eles podem se encaixar, e então aplica caso eles caiam bem naquela situação.

Além disso, eles me parecem só um conjunto esparso de exigências que individualmente são bem-fundamentadas, mas em conjunto não possuem coesão nenhuma. O que há neles como conjunto que diz que meu código vai ficar **sólido™** se eu aplicá-los?

Quem os defende os coloca em um patamar bem alto. Mas não sei se são tudo isso. Há quem critique (se for para ler uma só das que estão listadas abaixo, leia a primeira).

Crítica, [que no geral concordaram](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2hn91p/why_i_dont_teach_solid/): [Why I don't teach SOLID](http://qualityisspeed.blogspot.com/2014/08/why-i-dont-teach-solid.html)

Críticas e defesas: [SOLID is OOP for dummies](https://www.yegor256.com/2017/03/28/solid.html)

Outra crítica: [Not-so-SOLID OOP principles](https://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/not-so-solid-oo-principles.html)

Crítica criticada: [Re: Why every element of SOLID is wrong](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/5qto27/why_every_element_of_solid_is_wrong/)

Defesa contra algumas críticas: [In defense of the SOLID principles](https://blog.ndepend.com/defense-solid-principles/)

Gostaria de uma avaliação tão imparcial quanto possível da aplicabilidade desses princípios, e se eles trazem todos os benefícios que se alardeia deles.

Comment: Devo presumir que os negativadores são fãs do SOLID? :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Primeiro erro que as pessoas cometem é achar que o Uncle Bob é o criador do SOLID. Esta sigla foi criada pelo Michael Feathers. E os conceitos individualmente foram criados por outras pessoas, embora o Robert Martin tenha dado a sua versão de como cada um dos 5 itens deveriam ser interpretados. Então SOLID é mais umas daquelas coisas que cada um entende de um jeito, e, portanto, ninguém sabe ao certo o que é, e não serve como bom parâmetro, mas são boas dicas para se pensar e discutir o assunto.

E eles são meio que propositalmente vagos. Essa é uma das críticas que se faz ao princípio. O problema dele é que se a pessoa entende tudo o que ele é, não precisa dele, e se a pessoa apenas o usa como base para o que precisa realizar a pessoa fica "bitolada" e comete erros por seguir "fórmula mágica".

As ideias do SOLID são boas, mas é preciso sempre entender todo o contexto dele. Entendê-lo com profundidade para saber quando e como aplicar. O exagero no seu uso é um problema, como quase tudo que fazemos.

No geral o problema dele é colocar muito penduricalho, muito mecanismo no que deveria ser o domínio. E ele nem sempre produz a maravilha que se espera dele, mesmo quando feito certo. Ainda precisará de muita refatoração. Se é para refatorar, só coloque coisas dele quando precisa.

[image: Plug colocado na tomada através de gambiarra no meio do caminho]

Um outro problema relacionado é que ele mistura níveis de abstração. Você encontra no mesmo código coisas que expressam seu domínio e coisas que ajudam seu código "funcionar melhor".

O que você deve entender é que certas relações entre os objetos são difíceis de serem desfeitas e isto é o que importa em todo o SOLID. Não crie dependências onde uma refatoração será muito complicada. O segredo é eliminar dependências, é permitir composição. O que importa é a coesão, um conceito muito antigo.

## De que software estamos falado?

Isso é algo que sempre é deixado de lado. Estamos falando de um jogo? De algo embarcado? De uma aplicação interna? De um produto comercial? De uma biblioteca ou *framework* público? Ou de algo que não tem importância ou tempo de vida longo?

## Relação com OOP

Há quem diga que ele ajuda OOP. Há quem diga que vai contra, ou pelo menos que não é sobre OOP. Não me parece que seja sobre OOP, cada um fala sobre uma coisa e no geral fala sobre modularização, ou até fazer o oposto do que OOP prega.

## Princípios importantes

Eu gosto de outros princípios com prioridade, dois deles são o [YAGNI e o KISS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/101) que pregam que você deva fazer tudo simples e só o que precisa. Claro, com algum cuidado para não exagerar. De fato o KISS diz para fazer simples, mas não simplório, e o YAGNI não está dizendo para deixar a aplicação completamente pelada.

Curiosamente as pessoas que criaram e defendem o SOLID também defendem muito o código legado, a melhoria contínua, e a refatoração. Pois bem, não usar o SOLID até que ele seja necessário atende os dois princípios acima e ele pode ser aplicado quando necessário em código legado fazendo refatoração. Mas somente quando o ganho compensa.

Outro princípio que gosto muito, o que mais gosto, é o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Pela experiência que tive em mais de 35 anos desenvolvendo software, e em geral trabalhando anos no mesmo software, o que mais facilita a manutenção é o DRY. Eu chego exagerar no uso dele, mas não me traz grandes problemas. Ter uma informação canônica do sistema é fundamental. Quando você começa espalhar a informação vai perdendo o controle. E se precisar mudar algo que está espalhado terá problemas, além de ficar muito mais confuso entender o que está ocorrendo. Claro, o uso errado tentando reduzir uma repetição circunstancial pode causar problemas, por isso que sempre falo que é preciso saber modelar com maestria, entender o problema com profundidade.

Acho lamentável que andam criando uma onda contra o DRY. DDD é muito não DRY (em partes), SRP diz que deve ter um motivo para mudar uma classe, mas não que uma mudança de uma classe não deva mudar outras, e não ter que mudar outros lugares é mais importante.

> Além disso, eles me parecem só um conjunto esparso de exigências que individualmente são bem-fundamentadas, mas em conjunto não possuem coesão nenhuma. Por que meu código vai ficar sólido se eu aplicá-las?

Concordo. Mas acho que só botaram junto para vender a ideia mais facilmente. Esquece que o software será mais sólido. Entenda que isso em si é só marketing. Se apegue aos princípios individuais e os entenda. Ou aos [princípios originais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) que são mais importantes e que o SOLID foi criado para *marketá-los* melhor.

As pessoas gostam de comprar essas ideias, e quanto mais ela é repetida mais as pessoas querem segui-la. Cria um círculo virtuoso para quem entende o que faz e um vicioso para quem não entende. Quando as pessoas começam fazê-lo só porque leu que é algo que tem que fazer está errando por definição, mesmo que dê certo por coincidência.

## Dependency Inversion

Justamente o que ainda não aprendeu, que normalmente é implementado com o tal do [DI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101) ([já falei sobre ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327121/101)), é uma das coisas que mais crítico. Porque na maior parte das vezes é criado unicamente para facilitar o teste. Nem falam do que. E é usado ideologicamente. Qualquer coisa que seja colocando no código sem uma necessidade dele em si eu sou contra. Se ele é usado porque o software ficará melhor é ok. Se é usado para dar flexibilidade e isto é opcional também ok. Se é só para testes tem outras maneiras de realizá-lo. Geralmente é muito simples adicionar isso depois.

[image: Banco de plástico colocado no lugar de um banco de carro em um carro]

## Crítica a cada ponto

- **SRP**

  É legal e talvez o mais útil, mas é confuso. No começo as pessoas entenderam que era o DRY, hoje dizem que é outra coisa e isso me preocupa. É só sobre modularizar.

  Um dos problemas dele é que pode incentivar criar classes demais, funções demais, tornar o código complexo demais, ter que criar elementos de ligação, facilitadores, ou então códigos bem verbosos para expressar o que precisa por causa da existência de tantos componentes. E tendo tanta coisa fica mais fácil mexer individualmente neles, mas fica muito complicado manter e usar.

  É muito difícil definir bem o que é responsabilidade única. Quase todo mundo manda criar um `Cliente` que deriva de `PessoaJuridica`, e no momento que faz isto este `Cliente` passa ter pelo menos duas responsabilidades, mas "ninguém" enxerga isso. Isso é culpa do exemplo canônico esdrúxulo que usam para ensinar OOP.

  Em muitos casos uma mudança em uma classe exige a mudança em outra de forma associada para funcionar corretamente e de forma que não tem como você saber automaticamente. Refatorações para adicionar algo do SOLID tardiamente costumam ser obrigatórias nas linguagens com um bom sistema de tipos, caso contrário não compila. Em outras linguagens pode causar problemas em tempo de execução, a não ser que a pessoa crie no código um sistema de controle de tipagem, o que indica que ela escolheu a linguagem errada para fazer aquilo.

  Pra falar a verdade não temos ferramentas adequadas para lidar com isso, mesmo que seja desejável. E ninguém cria.
- **OCP**

  Como ideia geral é bom, mas na prática cria complexidade porque tudo exige fazer novas versões. É comum violar o DRY por causa disso (ironicamente deveria ser o oposto). Uma forma de evitar isso é separar bem as responsabilidades, mas quando o faz da maneira correta começa fugir de OOP.

  Em geral ela prega o abuso de herança, até do jeito certo, mas ainda assim usar herança onde talvez possa fazer de um jeito mais flexível e mais fácil com composição.

  Quando é tudo bem planejado e um novo tipo é criado herdado de algum tipo que foi pensado para ser base de outra coisa, pode funcionar. Quando você pega algo de um domínio e herda em outro domínio para flexibilizá-lo, tem algo errado, aí é melhor deixar o objeto tratar as diferenças.

  Uma das críticas que faço é que ela vê herança de uma forma básica. Hoje algumas linguagens possuem mecanismos mais sofisticados que permitem algo que fica no meio termo.
- **LSP**

  A ideia é muito boa, principalmente porque ela manda evitar fazer herança de forma atabalhoada, sem muito sentido. Evita-se assim o reuso pelo reuso, precisa ter um motivo para herdar. No fundo ela prega a composição sempre que fizer sentido, e faz muito mais do que as pessoas acham.
- **ISP**

  Em geral é bom, mas é mais sobre contratos. A parte ruim é quando exageram só pra seguir isso. Desde que você possa refatorar é melhor não segregar tanto assim e segregue depois quando necessário. Não entenda errado, é bom segregar, mas cuidado para não exagerar. O pior é quando a pessoa cria uma interface só por criar, sem que ela seja usada de fato. Esse é um erro que só peca quem é muito fanático por SOLID e não o entende totalmente, mas entre os desenvolvedores que não são novatos é comum cair nessa armadilha.
- **DIP**

  Já falei acima.

## Conclusão

Gosto da ideia do SOLID como dicas de coisas que você deva observar quando está desenvolvendo um software e pontos de partida para estudar mais sobre o assunto.

Nada dessas coisas garantem qualidade em software. Qualidade se dá quando a pessoa sabe o que está fazendo e é dedicada a fazê-lo corretamente.

Se o Uncle Bob faz isso e dá tudo certo pra ele, ótimo. Mas você tem certeza disto? Será que ele não acaba fazendo o mesmo trabalho que você faria não seguindo o SOLID quando tem que dar manutenção? Será que ele não tem mais facilidade só porque ele sabe fazer o certo independente de seguir o SOLID ou não? Não temos respostas para isto.

Quem provou que SOLID é bom? Devemos só acreditar que ele é? É religião?

SOLID é essencialmente bom, seu uso irresponsável não é. Os benefícios existem em casos específicos quando usado corretamente. Não fique só no SOLID e não se exija usar todo ele.

Tem coisas muito piores, SOLID nem é tão ruim assim, mas para ser mais justo tem princípios e guias melhores que atendem o mesmo objetivo. E se ele for aplicado com um ideal menos orientado a objeto talvez funcione melhor. Talvez o maior problema dele sejam os exemplos usados e soluções oferecidas.

No computo geral o importante é saber os prós e contras dele, é bobagem dizer que ele é ruim ou bom sem um contexto.

Eu preciso arrumar tempo para fundamentar esta resposta um pouco mais. Eu tenho a base do problema, mas ainda preciso de mais pesquisas para não deixar muito no ar. Em essência coloquei em português com minhas palavras o que está em todos os *links* da pergunta, e mais algum conhecimento.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Estou ciente sobre Michael Feathers. Agora, DIP é inversão, não injeção, de dependência. Dizem que são relacionados. Como não arrisco dizer que entendi o DIP, não consigo ver a relação que existe entre os dois.

Comment: @Piovezan sim, foi um lapso, mudei

Comment: Obrigado por trocar. Mas na resposta continua falando sobre injeção. São relacionados afinal? Desconfio que sim mas queria ter certeza. Realiza-se a injeção aplicando o princípio da inversão, seria isso?

Comment: São muito relacionados, um é o conceito, o outro é o mecanismo.

Answer (score 6):

**Sobre os Princípios na programação**

SOLID contém 5 princípios de **design de software**, mas não são todos os princípios existentes. Existem vários:

- **SOC** Separation of Concerns;
- **DRY** Don’t Repeat Yourself;
- **YAGNI** You Ain't Gonna Need It;
- **KISS** Keep It Simple, Stupid;
- **REP** The Release Reuse Equivalency Principle;
- **CCP** The Common Closure Principle;
- **CRP** The Common Reuse Principle;
- **ADP** The Acyclic Dependencies Principle;
- **SDP** The Stable Dependencies Principle;
- **SAP** The Stable Abstractions Principle;
- entre outros.

Os princípios citados acima não são do SOLID, mas também são princípios de **design de software**. São tão importantes quanto o SOLID para que o projetista possa saber o que é positivo e o que é negativo.

Não estou dizendo que uns são melhores do que outros, ou impondo uma hierarquia. Afirmo, entretanto, que todos são importantes para formar o conhecimento de um projetista. Saber quais práticas podem trazer benefícios e quais podem trazer desastrosas dores de cabeça conforme um software for evoluindo é a busca de todo bom projetista. Os princípios norteiam para esse conhecimento.

Haja vista que os princípios surgiram por causa de uma necessidade de entregar software de qualidade e em menos tempo possível. Numa época em que os grandes nomes da ciência da computação defendiam que "software deve ser fácil de manter"!

Entendendo que: **"menos tempo possível"** não significa entregar correndo. Muitos usam a palavra Ágil, afirmando que o software deve ser feito rápido, mas num sentido errado. O sentido da "agilidade" é entregar software de qualidade. Qualidade dá menos trabalho para mudar, menos trabalho para corrigir. Isso resulta em menos custo e menos tempo para manter e evoluir o software.

Como disse o Maniero: *"Eu gosto de outros princípios com prioridade, dois deles são o YAGNI e o KISS que pregam que você deva fazer tudo simples e só o que precisa. Claro com algum cuidado para não exagerar. De fato o KISS diz para fazer simples, mas não simplório, e o YAGNI não está dizendo para deixar a aplicação completamente pelada".* Os princípios ajudam a fazer bem feito, mas é preciso aprender a evitar exageros.

A experimentação e análise que deu origem aos princípios não foram feitas por programadores acalorados, mas por gente que sabia o que estava falando, gente do âmbito acadêmico (MIT, Oxford, etc) e empresarial de grande importância (IBM, por exemplo). Essa experimentação ocorreu por um período extenso (de mais de 30 anos) de pesquisa, por isso é difícil para nossa geração imediatista entendê-los. Não basta dar Control+C e Control+V.

Boa parte desses princípios surgiram em ambiente científico, em grandes universidades. O LSP do SOLID (Liskov Substitution Principle), por exemplo, foi feito por Barbara Liskov do **MIT** em [uma de suas publicações](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wing/publications/LiskovWing94.pdf).

Quando vemos artigos e críticas acirradas em blogs sobre "porque usar ou não usar princípios", percebemos o quão distantes as pessoas estão do real objetivo dessas preciosas ferramentas para projetistas de software. Os princípios existem para prover:

- Facilidade de manutenção;
- Reaproveitamento de código em outros projetos;
- Entregar evoluções e correções o quanto antes.

Veja o [Manifesto para Desenvolvimento Ágil de Software](http://agilemanifesto.org/iso/ptbr/manifesto.html).

**Outra coisa importante:** O objetivo não é seguir a risca todos os princípios a ferro e fogo em todos os momentos!! Se for assim, o software torna-se muito difícil de fazer, principalmente para os programadores menos experientes. Exigências e cumprimentos de regras a todo custo não é o objetivo!! **A importância dos princípios é relacionada a conhecimento**, permitir que o projetista conheça o que comprovadamente funciona e o que não funciona em diversas situações para que decida, por si mesmo, a melhor maneira de fazer um software que se adeque à realidade de sua empresa.

**Sobre o SOLID**

De fato, Robert Martin não "criou" os princípios SOLID, mas catalogou vários princípios que, segundo sua experiência, seriam os mais importantes por sintetizarem todos os outros (ver [Design Principles and Design Patterns](https://fi.ort.edu.uy/innovaportal/file/2032/1/design_principles.pdf)). Em outras palavras, entendendo e cumprindo estes princípios, estaria-se cumprindo, consequentemente os outros existentes na literatura.

Dessa lista, separou 5. No livro Clean Architecture, Martin explica que por volta de 2004 seu amigo Michael Feathers :

> *“enviou-lhe um e-mail dizendo que, se reorganizasse os princípios de seu catálogo, as primeiras letras soletrariam a palavra SOLID (sólido
>   em português)”*.

Foi neste ponto que nasceu o acrônimo.

**Robert Martin levou 20 anos para formular o catálogo**, com base em testes e experiência dele e de seus companheiros em diversas linguagens de programação. Não foi uma suposição, foi experimentação conjunta ou referenciada dos trabalhos de vários nomes da engenharia de software e ciência da computação: Barbara Liskov, Bertrand Meyer, David L. Parnas, Dave Thomas, Edsger Dijkstra, Kent Beck, Larry L. Constantine, Alistair Cockburn, Martin Fowler, Andrew Hunt, Michael Feathers e vários outros. Basta procurar alguns desses nomes na internet.

Para o bem da verdade, pouca coisa é do Robert Martin, a maioria dos princípios que ele catalogou é proveniente da literatura de alguns desses nomes. Abaixo, algumas das referências usadas por Martin para sintetizar e nomear os 5 princípios.:

- **SRP - Princípio da Responsabilidade Única:** David L. Parnas e Edsger Dijkstra (autor do SOC Separation of Concerns);
- **OCP - Princípio Aberto Fechado:** Bertrand Meyer e Larry L. Constantine (uns dos primeiros a falar sobre acoplamento e coesão);
- **LSP - Princípio da Substituição de Liskov:** Barbara Liskov;
- **ISP - Princípio da Segregação de Interfaces:** baseado no design pattern *Template Method*, da Gang of Four (Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides);
- **DIP - Princípio da Inversão de Dependências:** baseado no trabalho de Grady Booch, Meilir Page-Jones e Barbara Liskov;

Em uma de suas falas antigas, Martin afirma que os princípios são **importantes para projetistas Sênior e aspirantes a esse grau de conhecimento**, com experiência de longa data na área de design de software. Afirma ainda que os novos programadores, com pouca experiência poderiam não compreender o real sentido dos princípios e deturpá-los, mesmo com boa intenção, ao tentar resumi-los para repassar a seus colegas.

Isso explica bastante coisa! Na maioria dos lugares onde se fala de SOLID (blogs, sites e literaturas), é tão resumido que não dá para entender. SOLID não é simplório mas é simples de praticar. A transmissão de informação anêmica é que dificultou a jornada do SOLID para nós brasileiros entendermos de fato.

**Dica:** *Busque palestras do Robert Martin no youtube, tem várias antigas e novas.*

**O DIP (Dependecy Inversion Principle)**

Um grande exemplo dessa confusão é o funcionamento do *Princípio da Inversão de Dependência*. Ele é muito simples e afirma que se uma classe for depender de outra, esta deve ser mais estável.

> “o código que implementa a diretiva de alto nível não deve depender do
>   código que implementa detalhes de baixo nível” (Robert Martin, [Design Principles and Design Patterns](https://fi.ort.edu.uy/innovaportal/file/2032/1/design_principles.pdf)).

Em outras palavras, se a classe **A** depender da classe **B**, **B** deve ser mais estável que **A**, de forma que as dependências entre as classes sempre sigam em direção à estabilidade, dependendo de módulos mais estáveis que ela própria.

Se seu programa depender de um módulo onde os métodos mudam a cada versão, por exemplo, você terá sempre o trabalho de atualizar todas classes que o utilizam. Quanto mais estáveis as dependências forem, menos mudanças, mais agilidade, mais lucro e menos tempo perdido.

Simples e óbvio, como um software sólido deve ser.

**Conclusão**

Não é uma questão de defender ou criticar o SOLID. É uma questão de defender o conhecimento, e criticar a entrega de software ruim.

É muito fácil fazer software ruim, por isso é importante saber (entender de verdade) como pessoas mais experientes que nós lidaram com os mesmos problemas e os solucionaram.

Para uma ideia se tornar um **princípio** ou um **padrão**, é necessário que, primeiro, seja comprovado que muitos projetos fizeram uso dessa ideia e alcançaram os mesmos resultados. Isso só é possível com o tempo, com a experiência, com espírito de pesquisa e leitura de bons autores.

Abaixo, as referências para as obras usadas por Martin na formulação dos princípios:

- CONSTANTINE, Larry L. *Structured design. IBM Systems Journal, VOL13, NO 2*, 1974;
- DEMARCO, Tom. *Structured Analysis and System Specification*, Press Computing Series, Yourdon, 1979;
- DIJKSTRA, Edsger W. *On the role of scientific thought*. Burroughs Research Fellow, Netherlands, 1974;
- GAMMA et all. *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software*, Addison Wesley, 1995;
- BOOCH, Grady. *Object Solutions*, Addison Wesley, 1996;
- JACOBSON, Ivar. *Object Oriented Software Engineering a Use Case Driven Approach*, Addison Wesley, 1992;
- LISKOV e WING. *A behavior notion of subtyping*. Carnegie Mellom University: Pensilvânia, USA, 1994. Disponível em https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wing/publications/LiskovWing94.pdf. Acesso em 03/08/2019;
- MEYER, Bertrand. *Object-Oriented Software Construction*. Prentice Hall, 1988;
- PAGE-JONES, Meilir. *The Practical Guide to Structured Systems Design, 2d. ed.*, Yourdon Press Computing Series, 1988;
- PARNAS, David L. *On the Criteria To Be Used in Decomposing Systems into Modules*. Carnegie-Mellon University, 1971.

Comment: _"Veja alguns outros que existem"_ eu esperava DRY, KISS, YAGNI, preferir composição à herança, etc. e vieram os princípios de nível de pacote do Robert Martin. Acho que existem princípios de design mais importantes. Coincidência ou não, a lista de nomes que ajudaram ele a catalogar é praticamente a lista de autores do Manifesto Ágil. Eles endossam o SOLID? Tem referência disso? A explicação do DIP foi bem fácil de entender, obrigado. Essa associação de SOLID e entrega rápida eu acho escorregadia, mas é do Uncle Bob mesmo. O acrônimo surgiu em 2004? Ele publicou o livro original em 2002. :)

Comment: 1. DRY, KISS, YAGNI: já foi bem falado pelo Maniero, não achei legal repetir para não ficar
redundante e parecer uma correção. :)

Comment: 2. Entrega rápida: a primeira entrega de um software é sempre rápida e previsível (se for planejada, claro!). O problema começa conforme as evoluções vão acontecendo, principalmente se você trabalhar em um time. Por esse motivo, se princípios forem utilizados, o impacto das mudanças será menor e mais fácil de gerenciar... isso resulta em entregas mais rápidas. No fundo mesmo, a base do "Manifesto" não é desenvolver rápido no sentido de "correndo", mas no sentido de diminuição na perda de tempo e no retrabalho, comuns em softwares feitos sem nenhuma regra (cada um faz do jeito que quer).

Comment: 3. 2004 ou 2002: Boa pergunta, no livro Clean Architecture diz "In 2004 or thereabouts, Michael Feathers sent me an email saying that if I rearranged the principles, their first words would spell the word SOLID—and thus the SOLID principles were born."

Comment: Tem dois conceitos que sintetizam o SOLID, um dos motivos que não sou muito fã dele, ou sinteza de verdade ou vai no detalhe como outros princípios. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101

Comment: Eu ia citá-los, e também citar programar voltado para a interface e não a implementação. Mas enfim, você contou uma história muito interessante, sobre vinte anos de experimentação auxiliada por outros autores, à qual eu gostaria de ter a referência e também saber se esses outros autores endossam o SOLID. :)

Comment: Na verdade eles não endossam o SOLID, pois este foi uma iniciativa de Robert Martin para catalogá-los. Atualizei o texto, acrescentando os nomes cujos trabalhos contribuíram para a formulação de cada princípio. :)

Comment: Mudou a lista de nomes e a história ficou bem menos interessante. Foi um catálogo marketeiro de ideias esparsas criado por iniciativa individual do Robert Martin, que garante que a entrega não sai dos eixos se seguirmos os princípios. Blogs, respostas de Q&A e outras literaturas só valem se falarem bem, senão são curtas demais para terem argumentos contundentes. Os iniciados têm um leve ar de fanatismo, dão votos negativos a quem é cético e defendem "o conhecimento", menosprezando todo software que não é feito segundo essa filosofia, que também tem ares de bala de prata.

Comment: Nossa, estou realmente impressionado com sua visão negativa do conteúdo que partilhei de bom grado e sem nenhuma dessas intenções que citou... Obrigado Piovezan!

Comment: Obviamente fiz uma provocação gratuita -- talvez por isso você não tenha caído, mas tenha cuidado :) o caso é que essas referências por si sós não corroboram nada, o questionamento não era se os princípios individuais são bons, mas sim se o conjunto que formam é coeso e quais benefícios/malefícios ele traz. Isso de forma neutra e com embasamento. Você só trouxe o argumento "vinte anos coletando" e espera que se confie no trabalho dele, além de ter começado com uma história e terminado com outra.

Comment: O conteúdo é bom, tanto que votei nele, não tinha votado antes porque esgotei o meu limite de votos do dia que acaba de ser liberado novo dia. Tem muita coisa útil aí para ajudar muita gente entender melhor o assunto. Tem um tom menos neutro dizendo só coisas positivas, e nada tem só um lado, mas isso por si só não é um problema, mas tira um pouco da credibilidade de tudo o que está sendo dito, nada grave. O Piovezan só está querendo fazer um contraponto e mostrando um lado que tem no conceito. É um instrumento de marketing de uma pessoa que pegou coisas já existentes dando sua interpretação.

Comment: É uma coisa que pode ter ajudado algumas pessoas, mas ele não era necessário, não inovou em nada, tem um mérito de divulgar os conceitos escolhidos ali até pra dar certos as letras deixando outras coisas importantes de lado e dando importância  demais para o que é menos importantes (em alguns casos). E tem o demérito das pessoas criarem uma fixação por isso e evitar entender o todo, não é exatamente culpa do acrônimo, mas é algo que sempre acontece, alguém ganha com a desgraça dos outros. Por isso eu prefiro um aprofundamento do assunto do que se prender em 5 letras.

Comment: Basicamente isso e uma provocaçãozinha gratuita :)

Comment: Também concordo com isso! Por isso fiz questão de deixar claro que existem vários outros princípios, tão importantes como... tudo é importante quando se trata de aumentar seu conhecimento sobre o assunto... ainda tive o trabalho de citar as literaturas...

Comment: Princípios são importantes, ponto! São obrigatórios? Não. São nortes. Se o projetista é experiente em muitos projetos, provavelmente não precisará se preocupar com princípio algum, mesmo assim acabará cumprindo vários deles... foi o que aconteceu comigo. Quando vi, já cumpria vários... não só do SOLID... e nem sabia que existiam

Comment: Minha intenção foi tão somente expor o assunto com espirito de pesquisa! Como Maniero já havia feito contrapontos, excelentes por sinal, não seria interessante repetir (a não ser que eu tivesse contrapontos para acrescentar) para não ficar redundante e tirar a coesão do texto.

Comment: Focar em coisas que podem ser pesquisadas, esse foi meu objetivo. Tanto que fiz correções porque, num primeiro momento, havia confiado em minha cabeça... ao conferir nos meus livros, e identificando os pontos falhos, o mais correto seria mudar para que o conteúdo fosse verídico e pesquisável. Problema algum nisso. Nenhuma intenção de doutrinar ninguém, ainda mais uma pessoa experiente como o Piovesan.

Comment: O fato é que as pessoas gostam de acrônimos: DRY, KISS, SOLID... por isso eles existem... as pessoas gostam de modinhas. O próprio Dave Thomas (que participou do manifesto) critica o uso marqueteiro do termo "Agile" e companhia (DRY, KISS, SOLID) porque diminuem a necessidade de estudo na fonte, ou seja, as literaturas originais, que ficam parecendo receitas de bolo.

Comment: Agora, sejamos sinceros... quais dos programadores de nossa geração irão ler um livro de Bertrand Meyer sobre Design de Software contendo 1296 páginas? Poucos malucos como nós! Artigos científicos de Barbara Liskov e Edsger Dijkstra então? Praticamente ninguém... são científicos demais... nesse ponto a intenção de trazer esse conteúdo de forma mais acessível é plausível e interessante nos acrônimos ... mesmo que continuem empobrecendo o conteúdo original que era um espetáculo. Viva o conhecimento pra quem o deseja! Estamos no mesmo time! :D

Answer (score 4):

#### SOLID

Os princípios SOLID servem como métricas na orientação a objetos. Aplicar SOLID não é como um padrão de projeto, pois seus conceitos não são fórmulas, mas sim ideias que podem ser aplicadas no código. Para aplicar os princípios não existem regras rigorosas.

Solid é muito mais uma referência para conseguir identificar um código de qualidade, servindo como uma base para saber criar um código que é mais favorável a manutenção e a mudanças. Aplicar esses conceitos não é uma obrigação, tudo deve ser feito com ponderação, pois nenhuma regra deve ser seguida cegamente.

Enfim, saber esses princípios ajuda bastante a entender a orientação a objetos, mas é sempre importante ter senso critico, pois algo que é utilizado ou defendido sem ponderação perde o sentido. Acho SOLID essencial, mas não é uma fórmula mágica para desenvolver um código de qualidade.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Acho que o que me falta para entender o DIP é um bom exemplo. Os que vejo por aí não são bons ou não ilustram adequadamente o princípio. Ou então o princípio é mais simples do que parece e não há nada de mais para ser ilustrado.