# Qual a função e como usar os Controllers no Laravel

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, laravel-5, controller

Estou aprendendo `Laravel` por um canal, e me ficou a dúvida... Como devo criar meus `Controllers`? Até onde eu entendi, o `view` pede para ele, o `controller` vai validar e com sucesso chama o `model`.

Mas minha dúvida em geral é... Como devo estruturar meus controllers? Por exemplo:

`Views` são o que o usuário enxergam, assim fica fácil distinguir que serão páginas.

`Models` são estruturas de banco de dados (tabelas)

E `Controllers` entra como qual classificação? Preciso de um `Controller` para cada página que tenho? Minha única informação que tenho que eles utilizam funções.

Não sei se ficou claro ao ponto de entender a pergunta, qualquer coisa modifico, mas o resumo seria...

**Como estruturar um** `Controller` **no** `Laravel`?

PS: Deixando bem claro, sou novo em programação e gostei muito do framework `Laravel`, pelas coisas que ele faz junto com o PHP Artisan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então creio que você não deve ter olhado a documentação mas tudo bem, vou tentar ajudar.

`Controller` como o nome sugere é a classe Controladora, que envolve sua lógica e talvez sua regra de negócio, afinal você não deveria deixar isso no arquivos de rotas, você precisa do `Controller` para controlar uma determinada informação para sua `view`.

Você pode usar um `Controller` para várias páginas mais isso dependendo de você.

Lei informações relativas ao `MVC` para entender mais. Leia também sobre o [SOLID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336319/solid-%C3%A9-tudo-isso-que-dizem) .Você certamente deve ter lido pouco sobre Arquitetura de projetos, e se tiver mais dúvidas você também pode dar uma olhadinha na documentação do Laravel. Lá tem mais informações sobre `Controller` ,exemplos e mais usabilidades do `Controller` 
[Documentação Laravel sobre o Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers)

Aconselho também o que você veja o que é arquitetura de projeto `MVC`.
[O que é MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55486/o-que-%C3%A9-mvcmodel-view-controller)

Comment: Valeu! Acabei de ver um vídeo sobre SOLID de um homem do MVC e me ajudou muito a entender como devo utilizar e etc... Só não entendi muito bem a parte do D... Fiquei bem confuso na hora.

Comment: DIP: seria o princípio de inversão , fala sobre o desacoplamento. Achei um link que tem ilustrações pode ajudar a entender.
http://ramonsilva.net/boas-praticas/solid/inversao-de-dependencias/