# SOLID no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

O Laravel quebra os conceitos de **SOLID**?

> SRP - Single responsibility principle  Princípio da Responsabilidade
>   Única - Uma classe deve ter um, e somente um, motivo para mudar.
>
> OCP - Open/closed principle Princípio do Aberto/Fechado - Você deve
>   ser capaz de estender um comportamento de uma classe sem a necessidade
>   de modificá-lo.
>
> LSP - Liskov substitution principle Princípio da substituição de
>   Liskov - As classes derivadas devem ser substituíveis por suas classes
>   bases.
>
> ISP - Interface segregation principle Princípio da segregação de
>   interfaces - Muitas interfaces específicas são melhores do que uma
>   interface única geral.
>
> DIP - Dependency inversion principle Princípio da inversão de
>   dependência - Dependa de abstrações e não de implementações.

e se usarmos o comando `php artisan make:controller TestController -r` ele criará um *`Controller`* com todos os verbos `HTTP`, que fica como `index`, `edit`, `delete` e `store` em um único controlador.

No caso teriamos uma classe assim:

```
class TestController extends Controller 
{

public function index() {

 /*  Consulta  */

}
public function store() {

 /*  Insere  */

}

public function edit($id) 
{

/*  Edita  */

}
public function delete($id)
{

/*  Deleta  */

}
```

Isso não acaba violando um dos princípios do SOLID?

Fonte: [Medium](https://medium.com/thiago-aragao/solid-princ%C3%ADpios-da-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-a-objetos-ba7e31d8fb25)

Comment: E por que acha isto? E qual o problema vê nisso? Temos fonte aqui também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101

Comment: Eu acho (estou aprendendo ainda, por isso a pergunta) que são funções totalmente diferentes, então deveriam estar separados, não?

Comment: Como funções elas estão separadas, como unidade organizacional parece ter uma coerência, afinal todas são ações de um controlador. Dá pra questionar isso? Dá. Será que deve usar um MVC? Será que SOLID é tudo isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/336319/101 Será que as pessoas sabem o que dizem? Será q é simples definir o que é coeso ou não? Que no fundo é o que prega o SOLID. Será que esquecer OOP não ajuda mais no SRP? E no fundo parece que é só sobre ele q está falando e não o SOLID. O que tenho certeza é que decorar e seguir regras não faz software melhor.

Comment: @RodrigoPires Esse negócio de sólid em Laravel é tiro no pé programa o bang e seja feliz

Comment: @RodrigoPires da pra trabalhar com laravel trabalhando com solid de boa, não entendi qual e a treta...

Answer (score -1):

Cara, o SOLID é muito importante para sistemas grandes com regras de negócio complexas. Pra usar SOLID no Laravel você vai ter que fazer na mão. Você vai ter criar todos os diretórios da separação: Service, Repository, Entity(se for o caso), etc. Depois vai fazendo as injeções conforme o fluxo da arquitetura que você achar melhor. Em seguida vai aplicando as outras regras, criando intefaces e factories, aplicando a inversão de dependência e assim por diante. O Laravel não quebra o princípio SOLID é exatamente do controller que você vai chamar os services. Mas existem várias linhas de pensamento quanto a isso, vai ficar ao seu critério como vai ser o controller, mas nada de regras de negócio nele. Espero ter ajudado.