# Variáveis e métodos na classe abstrata, onde colocar?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança, classes-abstratas

`Cliente` e `Fornecedor` tem nome, telefone e e-mail em comum qual melhor forma de eu tratar isso, eu devo criar essas variáveis em comum na classe abstrata? ou existe uma forma melhor de eu fazer isso?

Pessoa (Abstract):

```
public abstract class Pessoa {

    public abstract String getNome();
    public abstract String getEmail();
    public abstract String getTelefone();  
}
```

Clientes:

```
public class Cliente extends Pessoa{

    public String nome;
    public String email;
    public String telefone;
    public String cpf;
    public String rg;

Cliente(String nome, String email, String telefone,String cpf, String rg){
    this.nome=nome;
    this.email=email;
    this.telefone=telefone;
    this.cpf=cpf;
    this.rg=rg;
}

public String getNome(){ return this.nome;}
public String getEmail(){return email;}
public String getTelefone(){return this.telefone;}
public String getCpf(){return this.cpf;}
public String getRg(){return this.rg;}   
}
```

Fornecedor:

```
public class Fornecedor extends Pessoa{

    public String nome;
    public String email;
    public String telefone;
    public String cnpj;
    public Long inscricaoestadual;

    Fornecedor(String nome, String email, String telefone,String cnpj, Long 
    inscricaoestadual){
        this.nome=nome;
        this.email=email;
        this.telefone=telefone;
        this.cnpj=cnpj;
        this.inscricaoestadual=inscricaoestadual;
    }

    public String getNome(){ return this.nome;}
    public String getEmail(){return email;}
    public String getTelefone(){return this.telefone;}
    public String getCnpj(){return this.cnpj;}
    public Long getIncricaoestadual(){return this.inscricaoestadual;}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deveria criar tudo o que é comum na classe abstrata, tanto campos quanto métodos, o que for possível porque é o mesmo em todas as classes. Mesmo que o comportamento dos métodos sejam potencialmente diferentes pode colocá-los e sobrescrever se for diferente na classe herdada, mas o contrato já está na classe superior.

## Outros problemas

Inclusive não faz muito sentido os métodos *getters* serem abstratos porque provavelmente eles terão implementação padrão e igual para todas as classes. Pode fazer sentido eles não serem finais, embora dê para questionar isso.

Na verdade dá pra questionar o uso de *getters* e *setters*. Virou meio que um padrão todo mundo fazer isso sem nem entender porque, as pessoas fazem porque viram em algum lugar que é pra fazer. Mas há também quem diga que não deve os usar. Já falei isso em várias perguntas, uma delas que pode servir de referência para começar estudar o assunto é [Métodos Getters e Setters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101). É melhor usar métodos que dizem o que está fazendo, você troca um mecanismo por um comportamento de domínio. Se for para usar mecanismo então por que não usar o campo de forma direta? Tem menos problema do que as pessoas imaginam quando opta-se pelo mecanismo porque já é [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101).

Há um outro problema conceitual porque fazendo esta herança poderá ter mais de um objeto no sistema para a mesma entidade (a pessoa). Isso parece bem errado e viola o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) de dados (a mesma pessoa hora é vista como um cliente e hora é vista com um fornecedor). Falei disso em diversas perguntas:

- [Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101)
- [Modelagem de lançamentos usando clientes e fornecedores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154748/101)
- [O que fazer se cliente pode ser tanto PF quanto PJ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101)
- [Herança e Polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101)
- [Como se modela um papel em orientação a objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101)

E tem outras se pesquisar aqui mesmo. Infelizmente se adotou um padrão errado há décadas atrás e aí como quase todo mundo só segue modelos prontos continuam fazendo errado. E depois culpam o paradigma de programação "antigo", o procedural, pelas "decisões" erradas delas próprias, e acham que falando que está programando orientado a objeto fica tudo certo. [Coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) é o nome do jogo, independente do paradigma. Esta forma não é coesa.

Se for a fundo também viola o [SRP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101) por manter no mesmo objeto dados que é de uma entidade (pessoa) e de um papel (cliente ou fornecedor). Também viola o [LSP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) porque acopla muito coisas distintas. [Prefira a composição no lugar da herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/101). De uma certa forma viola o SIP do [SOLID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101), até porque ele se confunde um pouco com o SRP. Os exemplos de OO costumam ensinar errado porque eles criam hierarquias artificiais que faz parecer que este tipo de herança é bom. [Tem um lado bom e ruim de SOLID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/336319/101).

Em alguns casos pode fazer sentido criar uma entidade única que tenha todos os papéis, principalmente como otimização de banco de dados evitando uma [relação 1:1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253550/101). O problema é que isso não fica muito bom na memória (dá para usar), aí você tem a chamada *impedance mismatch* de modelo e por isso as pessoas usam ORMs adicionando complexidade ao software. Por isso eu prefiro modelar na memória igual ao banco de dados, é tão mais simples...

`long` para inscrição estadual? Isto não faz sentido, não sei porque acertou nas outras e errou nesta, talvez porque está fazendo coisas aleatórios e acertando por coincidência. [Tipo do campo CPF ou CNPJ no banco de dados VARCHAR ou INT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101).

Comment: Entendo sua posição. Mas eu não consigo ver uma resposta na sua resposta,  o caminho a seguir para  que eu consiga resolver minha dúvida. bom tudo que eu escrevo eu aprendo na faculdade, claro você vai criticar mas eu não fico restrito a sala de aula também, por isso estou aqui, você mandou milhares de informações eu acabei ficando perdido e não sei onde começa ou termina o "erro" ou a má prática.

Comment: Esse é um problema hoje em dia. Todo mundo quer pronto e não consegue construir o conhecimento. Leia só o primeiro parágrafo e esqueça o resto. Deixe o resto para as pessoas que querem aprender fazer o certo. A primeira frase é o que quer. Me desculpe, eu sempre tento ensinar o certo e esqueço que as pessoas querem só a receita de bolo.

Comment: Analisando sua resposta com mais calma vejo que está mais completa que apenas uma resposta para minha pergunta, muito obrigado, desculpe as mensagens anteriores.