# O que é uma classe de serviço? E o que seria serviço nesse contexto?

Tags: classes, terminologia, engenharia-de-software

Qual seria a melhor definição formal para *classe de serviço*? Ainda nesse contexto, o que seria um Serviço e as condições para que essa classe receba esse nome? Percebi que é um termo muito utilizado mas não encontrei uma definição formal para o conceito aqui no SOpt.

Comment: Por enquanto fechei assim, mas posso mudar o motivo ou reabrir. Achei até que já havia sido respondido antes. Tem muitos contextos onde dá para usar esse termo mesmo dentro de TI.

Comment: existem muitos usos, em programação e sistemas operacionais, o que as vezes se misturam, fora serviços no entendimento de X empresa fornecer uma "porta" para Y empresa, não vejo como nada "padrão" para se relacionar a isto, claro, existem as APIs, protocolos e parametros/instruções usados para comunicação, que seria o básico para definir isto como um serviço, que geralmente está sempre "ativo" em algum lugar, pode ser que apareça uma resposta, até falando de SOAP ou REST, para tentar contextualizar como de programação, mas vai ter gente usando o termo nas mais absurdas situações (acho)

Comment: Posso editar perguntando no contexto da _programação web_ e da _engenharia de software_? Porque na resposta que o @Maniero [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423889/at%c3%a9-que-ponto-devemos-seguir-o-ocp) me deu no post do OCP, onde eu coloquei uma classe Service, ele questionou se seria realmente um serviço, e isso me fez questionar se minha definição está correta ou nao.

Comment: Aí nem é questão de definir o que é um serviço, mas se aquilo seria uma classe de serviço, mas já começou dar um contexto, indo por esse caminho a pergunta começa melhorar.

Comment: Essa é minha dúvida, quando uma classe pode ser denominada uma classe de serviço e quais serias as condições para que recebesse esse nome? E para que eu, e futuros usuários, possam entender isso, seria interessante uma definição de serviço nesse contexto.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, espero que esteja adequada agora para os padrões do site e possa servir para ser respondida.

Comment: @Maniero a pergunta ficou adequada?

Comment: Não consigo entender o porquê de tantos votos negativos, é uma questão que ainda não foi respondida formalmente aqui no SOpt e as pessoas invés de responder negativam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há um pouco de controvérsias sobre o que é e existem contextos diferentes ainda mesmo para a classe de serviço. Por exemplo se usar a disciplina do DDD ele tem uma definição clara para o que propõe, que não quer dizer que deva ser a definição de outras pessoas e há quem questione tudo isto.

[O Martin Fowler critica o uso de classes que modelam objetos anêmicos](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html), portanto só tem a estrutura e não tem comportamentos que ficam em classes de serviço bem segregadas. Então ele fala que os serviços devem ser adicionais ao modelo básico, mas não está claro qual é o limite.

Alguns dirão é que se pode ser chamado em mais de um lugar, mas nem sempre isto é claro antecipadamente no projeto, na teoria é lindo, na prática só dá certo por coincidência, por isso muita gente prefere só ter serviços, na dúvida está separado.

De uma certa forma podemos pensar meio como normalização. Se usa só em um lugar e você pode garantir isto deve estar na classe que é usada, seja no modelo, controlador ou outro lugar. Se pode ser usado em mais de um lugar então precisa de uma entidade própria para lidar com isso e fazer a relação com tudo o que necessita dele. Uma classe serviço é aquela que possui comportamentos que não se encaixam em outras classes de forma natural e encapsulada.

Acredito que essas classes de serviços são ligadas ao domínio e a classe usada na pergunta seja ligada ao controlador (não sei se deveria, pode ser um erro, não dá para afirmar).

Ou seja, isto propõe esquecer esse negócio de orientação a objeto porque o procedural sempre foi bom quando feito corretamente e de forma modular. Ou quase isto, algumas pessoas contestarão isto.

Curiosamente essas classes costumam ser parecidas ou iguais às classes [utilitárias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/101) ou de ajuda ([*helper*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54884/101)) que muitos criticam existir, mas que elas exercem uma função importante. Alguns dão definições um pouco diferentes para isto, mas ainda guarda semelhança, ainda que um serviço deva ser algo mais específico. Alguns dizem que a diferença é que o serviço é algo bem definido, enquanto que um *helper* é gambiarra, mas me parece uma definição do tipo "marcar território".

Eu já vi definições contraditórias do termo.

Minha relação de amor e ódio com DDD é assim, eu ainda não domino totalmente a disciplina e sempre digo que ela tem ideias muito boas, corrige muito erro ou formula uma técnica que ajuda as pessoas fazerem código melhores, mas passa um pouco do ponto e aí a implementação torna qualquer código muito complexo, portanto a implementação da ideia não é boa. Eu faço algumas coisas que talvez um dia eu possa organizar e criar um *framework* (a chance não é tão grande por falta de tempo) que use a base do DDD de um jeito melhor.

De maneira alguma você só pode criar uma classe de serviço se estiver usando DDD.

Então na [pergunta *linkada*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/423889/101) tem um exemplo usando um classe de serviço, mas eu não sei se isto é um serviço porque serviço não é bem definido. Mas também não sei porque não tem todo o contexto, se ali faz sentido porque não vi o domínio (modelo), e como está escrito lá tem problemas no código e faz coisas estranhas, o que começa indicar que não é um serviço, ele mistura responsabilidades do modelo com a ação do controlador, pior mistura mais de um modelo de forma inadequada. Talvez seja só um serviço não bem implementando, mas ainda ser um serviço. A ideia foi boa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).